# Is it ever possible to have Big O less than O(1)?

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o, time-complexity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [are there any O(1/n) algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905551/are-there-any-o1-n-algorithms)

Is it ever possible for your code to be Big O less than O(1)?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905551/are-there-any-o1-n-algorithms

Comment: Dang you, Nick, you beat me. :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O(1) simply means a constant time operation.  That time could be 1 nanosecond or 1 million years, the notation is not a measure of absolute time.  Unless of course you are working on the OS for a time machine, than perhaps your DoTimeTravel( ) function would have O(-1) complexity :-)

Comment: Time traveling concept is cool :) +1 for that

Answer (score 2):

Not really. `O(1)` is constant time. Whether you express that as `O(1)` or `O(2)` or `O(.5)` really makes little difference as far as purely big O notation goes.

As noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905551/are-there-any-o1-n-algorithms), it is technically possible to have an `O(1/n)`, but that no real-world useful algorithm would satisfy this (though some do algorithm's do have `1/n` as part of their algorithmic complexity).

Comment: The sql statements like "DROP TABLE" and "DELETE FROM TABLE"
Show O(1/N) beheaviour.

Comment: How do you figure that? `n` being the number of tables, not the number of records in the table, since the *table* is the input, and usually all these operations need to do is delete a reference to the table.

Comment: `DELETE FROM TABLE` might have O(1/N) characteristics, dependant on implementation, but I would doubt if this would show up unless you were trying to delete over half the table.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that would take less than O(1) (constant time) would be an operation that did absolutely nothing, and thus took zero time. But even a NOP usually takes a fixed number of cycles...

Comment: A fixed number of cycles? How many cycles does it take to read an instruction and do nothing? I wouldn't expect a NOP to take more than 1 cycle...

Comment: Of course, it depends on architecture.

Comment: Not really. It's constant, but it always takes time, atleast one cycle, but however long it takes to read the instruction and discard it.