# Is it true that if the growth ratio of denominator is larger than the numerator then it is theta(1)?

Tags: big-o

I need to prove this

(n+2)/2^n=Θ(1)

i found an explanation saying that because the growth ratio of the denominator is larger than the growth ratio of numerator but i don't believe that's the case for every division
1/n isn't Θ(1) for example.
if it is possible i must find this without the use of the limit definition

Comment: Is that (n + 2) / 2^n, or n + 2/2^n?

Comment: (n+2)/2^n i will change it

Comment: It's not Theta(1). (n+2)/2^n is not bounded below by any non-zero multiple of 1, which is one of the conditions for it being Theta(1). (The other condition being bounded above, which it does satisfy).

Comment: @PaulHankin I think Ω(1) does bound it from below. May you add an answer to be more specific where my reasoning might be wrong?

Comment: @PaulHankin You're right, of course. I did not realise that when talking about functions that tend toward 0, Θ is no longer insensitive to constant terms. I deleted my answer to avoid spreading lies :)

Comment: @AKSingh There is some discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677537/what-is-the-difference-between-o1-and-%CE%981

Answer (score 1):

You may try to answer this by using recursive proof.

## Proving that it is O(1)

### Initialization

For n0=2, (n0+2)/2^n0 = 1 <= 1

### Generalization

Let n a non nul natural number such that (n+2)/2^n <= 1.

Then, n+2 <= 2^n

Since n >=1 , 2^n >1, so 2^n + 2^n > 2^n + 1

So, n+2 + 1 <= 2^n +1 <= 2 * 2^n, meaning that (n+1)+2 <= 2^(n+1), so ((n+1)+2)/2^(n+1) <= 1

### Conclusion

For all n >= n0 = 2, (n+2)/2^n <= 1, meaning that (n+2)/2^n = O(1)

## Edit

As @Paul Hankin mentioned, it isn’t Theta(1) since its limit is 0.

Comment: That does not follow from the definition of big-Omega though. See @Paul Hankin 's comment.