# Function which is Big O(1) but not Ω(1)

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

Can some help me with a function which is Big O(1) but not Ω(1) and the other way around? Some explanation would greatly help.

Comment: when would a function be O(1) but not Ω(1)? Think about what each one means.

Comment: Since O(1) is a constant, there cannot be a function which is upper bounded by O(1). This is what I think...

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209139/is-the-time-complexity-of-the-empty-algorithm-o0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Big-O means <= and big Omega means >=, so a function that is O(1) but not Omega(1) is f(n) = 1/n.  For the other way around, f(n) = n works.

Comment: @Keith: How could you ever construct an algorithm taking a fractional number of steps?

Comment: You can't.  But that wasn't the question.

Comment: Then,is this a valid question in the first place?

Comment: Nice catch, I was thinking about algorithm as well. +1.

Comment: The question is perfectly valid if you are just talking about functions.  If a function represents an algorithm's running time, however, it must be at least 1.  In any case, the reverse (Omega(1) but not O(1)) is perfectly valid.

Comment: Then, it was my mistake to tag this in Algorithms.
But, my feeling is, since O(1) is a constant, how can it bound any curve. Or may be just Theta(1) is only constant?
I am just starting with algorithms, please bare with my silly questions

Comment: @Ringo: O(1) is a set. Namely the set of bounded functions. And n -> 1/n (for natural numbers n) is a member of that set. Ω(1) is another set, namely the set of functions bounded away from zero, and n -> 1/n is not a member of that set. Now, since the running time of an algorithm can not in any reasonable way (that I could imagine) decrease with larger inputs, *in the context of algorithmic complexity*, it is reasonable to treat algorithms with running time in O(1) as taking essentially constant time.

Comment: So, Theta Θ(1) should be a constant, am I right?
That cleared many doubts of mine.

Thanks Christopher Creutzig, Keith Randall and others.

Comment: Also, by my understanding, O(1) and Ω(1) are disjount sets, is this correct?

Comment: @Ringo: No, Θ(1) = O(1) ∩ Ω(1) is the set of all functions f which have a finite, non-zero limit. Which, for algorithmic complexity, is “essentially constant.” (Strictly speaking, Θ(1) is, of course, a constant. A constant set of functions. In the same sense that the sin function is a constant – the function itself does not change …)

Comment: Alright, I got your point. That was very helpful... Thank you.
I have one more doubt, in cormen's Algorithm book, I read Θ(n^0) is same as Θ(1). How is this possible if Θ(1) = O(1) ∩ Ω(1), as O(1) has n^(1/2) as its function?

Comment: @Ringo, I'm confused by your question.  O(1) does not have n^(1/2) in it.  n^(1/2) grows with n.  But n^(1/2) is in Omega(1).

Comment: Ok, I got it. I was confused before asking this question. Now I it seemed to be clear. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelMadsen AFAIK There are Quantum Computing algorithms which might perform computations faster than amount of data - search in n elements in O(sqrt(n)) time. Till it's still theoretical, cause such Quantum hardware is not created yet, algorithms are beeing maid. (Currently created adiabiatic quantum computers, are only one of possible types).