# How to compare 3 dimensional arrays within O(0)?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, iterative-deepening

So I tried to make a solving algorithm for a rubiks cube that makes use of a 3 dimensional array however since a 3 dimensional array's values can not be compared to another array's values, my if statement always return False.

My code is currently this however the debug part always returns false as it can not correctly be compared. This will also run aprox 2*27^10  times so the comparison has to be fast. And using a list and a for loop wont work fast enough for this.

Current code:

```
public void Solving(int[,,] Tbs) // 3d array cube that has to be solved
{
    bool found = false;


   List<char> movements = new() {'F','U','L', 'R','D', 'B' };
    Queue<int[,,]> activeFromSramble = new();
    Queue<int[,,]> activeFromSolved = new();

    if (DefaultCube() == DefaultCube()) // for debug purposes defaultcube has all have the same values inside
        Console.WriteLine("Works");
    else
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Broken");
    }
    Dictionary<object, object> fromSC = new();
    Dictionary<int[,,], int[,,]> fromSOL = new();
    activeFromSramble.Enqueue(Tbs);
    activeFromSolved.Enqueue(DefaultCube());
    fromSC.Add(Tbs, Tbs);
    fromSOL.Add(DefaultCube(),DefaultCube());
    while (found == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It");
        int[,,] oldCube = activeFromSramble.Dequeue();
        if (fromSOL.ContainsKey(oldCube))
        {
            found = true;
                        
            Console.WriteLine("FOUND");
            
        }
        foreach (char c in movements)
        {
            
                for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    int[,,] newCube = PermCube(oldCube, c, i);
                    if (fromSC.ContainsKey(newCube)) // of hij in eigen lijst staat met key
                        continue;

                fromSC.Add(newCube, oldCube); 
                    activeFromSramble.Enqueue(newCube);
                   
                }
        }
        
        oldCube = activeFromSolved.Dequeue();
        if (fromSC.ContainsKey(oldCube))
        {
            found = true;
            Console.WriteLine("FOUND");
                        
        }
        foreach (char c in movements)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {

                    int[,,] newCube = PermCube(oldCube, c, i);
                    if (fromSOL.ContainsKey(newCube))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    {
                        activeFromSolved.Enqueue(newCube);
                        fromSOL.Add(newCube, oldCube);
                    }
            }
        }

    }


    
}
```

Comment: What does `O(0)` mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209139/is-the-time-complexity-of-the-empty-algorithm-o0 mostly just how fast an algorithm is with O(0)  it will be fast enough and a list foreach will be generally too slow for the algorithm. For example the Dictionary uses a hash key that doesnt have an index property and thus can really fast search for any keys that it might contain.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare the data in variable sized arrays in constant time. Some possible approaches:

1. Use a hash. This lets you amortize the time to generate the hash over many comparisons. Use a strong hash that has a negligible chance of collisions. Consider using an immutable data structure to ensure the hash always matches the data.
2. Use another data representation. Figure out the minimum amounts of bits you actually need, and store these as compact as possible. This should reduce the comparison time as much as possible.
3. Use a fast hash, but fallback to checking the actual data if the hashes match.

Comment: Any possibilities to do it in O(n) or O(1) or log(n)?

Comment: @LukasvanDee worst case will always be `O(n)` with n being the total number of elements in the array. But it depends on usage, if you need less than 64 bits the comparison time will be constant. If you do many more comparisons than you have objects, a hash should result in amortized constant time. If you have more than say 2^256 comparisons,  optimizations will be irrelevant since it will take to much time regardless.