# Algorithm whose worst case complexity is inversely proportional to input size?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any O(1/n) algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905551/are-there-any-o1-n-algorithms)

Any algorithm whose complexity decreases with increase in input size?

I am talking about worst case performance.

In general we know math graphs whose magnitude decreases with the input size but do we have any meaningful algo that matches these graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
 Mystery(array[1..n])
 1. x := fn(0)
 2. for i = 1 to floor(1,000,000 / n) do
 3.    x = fn(x)
 4. return x
```

All such algorithms are constant-time, asymptotically speaking, for obvious reasons.

EDIT:

Actually, this is asymptotically O(log n), if integer division is logarithmic, which I believe it is. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations As such, my answer would be that there aren't really any O(1/n) algorithms. O(1) is the smallest complexity class there is... unless there's a way to make an algorithm that can know the inverse of its input size without computing it!

EDIT2:

I just thought of perhaps passing 1,000,000 / n to the function as input... but that's not really a genuine solution, since the algorithm would have no way to tell if that condition were violated, and the caller would need to compute it anyway. Note that a lot of this discussion isn't particularly relevant if you're taking arithmetic operations to be constant time, as I'm pretty sure they are on computers with fixed-size intrinsic types and instruction sets operating on defined register sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
f(Collection c, query q):
  if q in c:
    do something fast!
  else:
    compute Ackermann function!

f*(Array a, int i):
  if a[i] == i: //Or some other condition that takes constant time to verify,
                //assume i is within bounds
    do something fast!
  else:
    compute Ackermann function!
```

Well, of course, the performance of this relies on the probability that a[i] == i. I haven't done any thorough analysis but I guess, to compute this probability, you need some form of assumptions about the nature of the array and how f* gets called.

It's fun to think about but I can't imagine a case I'll ever actually encounter this scenario.

**EDIT:** original answer was f, but changed it to f* in an attempt to accommodate harold's comment. After f* I rest my case and will just be lurking.

Comment: Doesn't really work - how much time does it take to find whether `q` is in `c`? At least O(1)

Comment: Hah! Okay. Nice point. I give up then. Will just keep watching this if anything nice actually comes up. :))

Comment: I'm afraid array access also takes O(1)