# Is it possible for a monotonically decreasing function to be the time complexity of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I suppose it's possible to have a time complexity such as `n-1`, `n-2`, etc.

But is it possible to have an algorithm with, let's say, `O(1/n)` time, or even space complexity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any O(1/n) algorithms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905551/are-there-any-o1-n-algorithms)

Answer (score 2):

You can't go below O(1) in complexity.

O(0) is undefined => can't have zero/instant cost operations and O(c) = O(1).

And in fact O(n-1) = O(n-2) = ... = O(n-c) = O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a function f(n) you can compute in constant time, the time complexity of

```
procedure comp(n)
  for i=1 to f(n) do
    some computation in O(1)
```

will be in O(f(n)).
You can build an algorithm with a O(1/n) time complexity → take f(n)=1000/n.

As f is a positive function, if f is monotonically decreasing then f must have a constant limit toward +oo and in fact such we would have O(f(n))⊆O(1).