# asymptotic - inverse series big o

Tags: algorithm

Is it correct?

```
1/(1+2+.....+sqrtN) =1/((N+sqrtN)/2)=2/(N+sqrtN)=1/N =O(1/N) =O(1)
```

Or is it equal to O(N), if so then what does N in O(1/N)  refers. Is N here deals with very large operations if so then sum of sqrtN operations must also equal to N and hence result into O(1).

I'd be happy to know where am I getting wrong about big O ratio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905551/are-there-any-o1-n-algorithms)

Comment: wait what? these summation is meant to evaluate some real life machine code operations ? none of the statement make mathematical sense either

Comment: @yerken, can you mark your answer regarding the series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

`O(1/N) <= O(1)`

An algorithm to be O(1/N) means that it executes asymptotically in less steps than the algorithm consisting of a single instruction. If it executes in less steps than one step for all `N > N0`, it must consist of precisely no instruction at all for those n. Since checking `'if N > N0'` costs at least 1 instruction, it must consist of no instruction for all `N`.

Summing up: The only algorithm which is `O(1/N)` is the empty algorithm, consisting of no instruction.

Comment: well thank you for your advice regarding empty function. but what shall be the complexity of given function 1/(1+2+...+sqrtN). is it O(N)? do explain

Comment: It's programming community - not mathematical. You can visit [math.se] for functional analysis. On [so] we might consider analyzing growing functions. The rest of functions is actually out of our interests.