# Complexity of f(n) = 1/n^5

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

## The task

I am trying to find out the asymptotic tight bound for a function,
f(n) = 1/n^5.
It will be great if someone can provide suggestions or solutions on how to find the asymptotic tight bound for f.

## What I have come up with

We can safely assume that 0 < f(n) <= 1.
Therefore we can say the upper bound complexity of f is O(1).

Also we can say the lower bound complexity of f is Omega(1/n^5).
So, the asymptotic tight bound of this function is Theta(1/n^5).

Comment: @kenneth - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905551/are-there-any-o1-n-algorithms

Comment: @libik The linked question is about algorithms, the OP never made any mention of those. Seems irrelevant to me. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @libik I have seen that question before. But it is different from what I asked.

Comment: I think the question would fit better to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A critique of your solution

While you arrived at a conclusion, the arguments you gave are not particularly good.

### The upper bound

While we certainly have f in O(1), this is entirely irrelevant.
You do not use it and I do not see any way in which it could be useful.

### The lower bound

The lower bound is correct but you do not give any reason *why*.
One might argue for this to be trivial
but the triviality should be pointed out explicitly
if this is the line of reasoning you want to follow.

### The tightness

Without any further reasoning you claim your lower bound to be tight.

## A (trivial) solution

For any function f, the function f is a tight bound for itself.

### The Homework

Prove this rigorously yourself.