# Multi-Variable Big O Analysis of Complex Fractions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

1. Suppose (without code) we have a function that takes two inputs `n` and `k`. Assume that there is no relationship between these two variables. Let's say that we can simplify the Big O time complexity to `O(n/k + n + k)`. From here, would we be able to achieve a tighter bound? My thinking is as follows:

   When handling analysis with multiple unrelated inputs, it is best to consider which term is dominant when each variable is very large. When `k` is very large, the `k` term is dominant over the `n/k` term. Moreover, as we approach very large numbers of k, the `k` term will approach positive infinity while the `n/k` term will approach `0`. Additionally, when `n` is very large, the `n` and `n/k` terms "tie". That is, both values will approach infinity at relatively comparable rates. Since the `n/k` term is not the dominant term for either variable, it would seem logical to remove it from our expression. So, our bound would be `O(n + k)`. Is this correct?

2. As an extension, suppose we have a function that takes a single input of `n`. Let's say that we can simplify the Big O time complexity to `O(1/n)`. Based on the logic I applied above, as we approach very large numbers, the `1/n` term approaches `0`. In this way, a constant of an arbitrary value, which does not contain an `n`, would dominate the `1/n` term. So, would it be fair to simplify the time complexity of this algorithm to `O(1)`?

Comment: I think you are correct in your thinking. *O(1/n)* is a little philosophical; see e.g. this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905551/are-there-any-o1-n-algorithms