# Practical way to learn about analysis of algorithms

Tags: algorithm

I am an undergraduate Computer Science student,wanting to take up research in the discipline.I was wondering whether there was a practical way to feel about the asymptotic complexities(big oh and all) and to see how an algorithm was better than other.

Comment: A textbook on algorithms would be a good start. Try *Introduction to Algorithms*, by Cormen et al.

Comment: I would expect your institution to offer an algorithm-analysis class you could take. Since you're already enrolled there, that seems like a very practical way to learn it.

Comment: @Sneftel,I am using it but I want learning to be more practical oriented so that I can see how one algorithm is better than the other.

Comment: @RobKennedy,the algorithms class was theoretical,just rote learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start is read book about algorithms, maths and something about [asymptotic computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_computational_complexity), [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) ([problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066660/algorithm-analysis-question?rq=1) and [compare](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)) and other like that.

> a practical way to feel about the asymptotic complexities(big oh and all) and to see how an algorithm was better than other

Nice idea seems to be watching [the charts](http://science.slc.edu/%7Ejmarshall/courses/2002/spring/cs50/BigO/), like here. However, the best way is just to check. :)

Let me give an example (in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)).

## Example

**Problem:** We have a rod length n and we can cut it for free. Different length, different cost. How to earn the most?

**Data:** We have a table of cost (integers always), and two functions.

**Code:**

```cpp
 constexpr unsigned int m  = 50; // any m>=n
 const std::array<unsigned int, m+1> costs {{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 666}};
 //whatever values, costs[0] = 0
 unsigned int cut_rod(unsigned int);
 unsigned int cut_rod2(unsigned int);
 int main(void)
  {
   unsigned int n, option;
   std::cin >> n >> option;
   std::cout << (option==2 ? cut_rod2(n) : cut_rod(n)) <<'\n';
  }
```

cut_rod is simple brute option. It has **O(n)** memory, taking into account an array of costs (plus recursion).

```cpp
 unsigned int cut_rod(const unsigned int x)
  {
   if(x == 0)
    return costs[x];
   unsigned int best = 0;
   for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= x; ++i)
    best = std::max(best, costs[i] + cut_rod(x-i));
   return best;
  }
```

cut_rod2 is similar, and has **O(n)** memory too, with twice as large const hidden in O notation (if recursion is skipping).

```cpp
 unsigned int cut_rod2(const unsigned int x)
  {
   static std::array<unsigned int, m+1> calculated{{0}};
   if(x == 0 || calculated[x] != 0)
     return calculated[x];
   unsigned int best = 0;
   for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= x; ++i)
    best = std::max(best, costs[i] + cut_rod2(x-i));
   return (calculated[x] = best);
  }
```

As we can see, the difference is small, at least in the code. Now we can compile it.

> g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic source.cpp

And just check, run and see times. For better effect, I suggest make file1.in and file2.in with the same n, and other function. Than you can use time.

> time ./our_program.out < file$.in

I suggest you use the script that will create file_$i_1.in and file_$i_2.in. Edit files can be tiring. Have a nice check!

*After you can have a look at the analysis.*

## Complexity analysis

As already mentioned, the complexity of the memory is linear relative to the length of the rod. Each recursion examines the rod length less than his father, so it's linear. Arrays too. Identical in both cases.

**Memory: O(n)**

Time complexity is more rummy.

Let's start with the first function. Assume *T(i)* as the number of function calls for the parameter i. Than easy, for *i* is performed i-1 children, witch performed...  (T(0) = 0):

[image]

**Asymptotic Computational complexity: Θ(2<sup>n</sup>)**

In the second, function does not compute twice the same. So when we asking about i, witch was calculated, we have answer in **O(1)** time. For all i from 1 to n, we ask i time, so easy is prove complexity, however it's not hard to see ;) it's **Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)**

**Asymptotic computational complexities: Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)**

I firmly believe, if you checked the duration of the program for different n, you clearly feel the difference between different asymptotic complexities. :)