# What does Θ(deg(u)) mean?

Tags: big-o, analysis, adjacency-list

I have never heard this before, or maybe I have heard it in other terms?
The context is that for adjacency lists, the time to list all vertices adjacent to *u* is `Θ(deg(u))`.
 Similarly, the time to determine whether *(u,v)∈ E* is `O(deg(u))`.
If the implementation of the adjacency list is an array, then I assume it would be constant time to find *u* in the array.
 If all adjacent vertices are linked to *u*, then I believe it would take `O(n)` time to list or find all vertices, where n is the number of adjacent vertices.
 Is that essentially what `Θ(deg(u))` means?

Comment: I this a programming question cus I can't really tell.Forgive me for my noobness.

Comment: This is more mathematical than programming, but fits securely within basic theoretical CS and so SO is more appropriate than say Math or Theory in my opinion.

Comment: I was debating where to post it because it is more math oriented, but I hope that this is the right place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Θ(n) and O(n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-on)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Θ(deg(u))` = Big-Theta of the degree of `u` = the time is tightly-bounded (bounded from above and below) by the degree of vertices. In the case of an adjacency-list representation of the graph, the degree of a vertex `u` is `|adj[u]|` the size of the list for `u`.

Thus, to iterate over the adjacent vertices of `u` by an adjacency list is tightly-bound to the number of vertices adjacent to `u` (algorithmic facts sound redundant sometimes, don't they?).

The difference between Big-O and Big-Theta is that Big-O is an upper bound, whereas Big-Theta states a tight bound from above and below. That is, the same expression serves as a bound, but with a different coefficient m and x0. See [the family of Bachmann-Landau notations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) on wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure `deg(u)` means "the degree of `u`", i.e. the number of edges that contain `u`. In an adjacency list representation, that number will also be the size of the adjacency list for `u`, so iterating it requires `Θ(|list|)`, which is `Θ(deg(u))`.