# Recurrence Relations in Data Structures

Tags: math, data-structures, recurrence

In my Data Structures Class, we're looking at recurrence relations like T(n) and big O problems O(n). I'd appreciate any resources for learning these, my textbook doesn't cover T(n), and the professor skips over lots of steps.

I haven't seen a good, step-by-step method for solving these things. I realize that every problem is unique, but there has to be some sort of framework for doing these.

Thanks.

Comment: A good place to start is this [SO discussion][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-on

Answer (score 1):

Check [Concrete Mathematics - A Foundation for Computer Science](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025), it's a brilliant book with lots of examples and exercises.

Answer (score 1):

Another great book is [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844).  It has a pretty thorough section on solving recurrence relations.

You are right, there is a generalized method for solving simple recurrence relations called the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).  (The explanation in *Introduction to Algorithms* is much better than the Wikipedia page.)  It doesn't work for every case, but it solves a lot of common ones.