# Java - Count the occurences of the elements of array A in array B

Tags: java, arrays

Assuming that B[] is longer than `A[]`, I'm trying to figure out a way to count the number of times all the elements of `A[]` occurs in `B[]`.

So say `a[]{A,B}` & `B[A,B,C,A,C,A,B,B,A,B]`

It would return 3

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: Why 3 and not 4? `A1,B1,C,A2,C,A3,B2,B3,A4,B4` I can see: 4 `A` and 4 `B`. They are not in order, but they appear 4 times both of them (Added numbers to count each)

Comment: @Frakcool every `A` immediately followed by a `B`, and there's only three of those in the specified example.

Comment: @Aominè it's not specified in the description, it only says: *"I'm trying to figure out a way to count the number of times all the elements of `A[]` occurs in `B[]`."* So, all elements of `A[]` appear 4 times in array `B[]`. That's why I'm asking why. If they should be in order, then yes, it's 3. But unless OP clarifies it's still something to take note (at least for me)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the number of equal values in two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666650/how-to-count-the-number-of-equal-values-in-two-arrays)

Comment: Sorry (haven't slept in several days), should have specified that I meant all elements of A[] in that exact order in B[]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic method that counts occurrences of one array within the other:

```
public static <T> int countOccurrences(T[] hayStack, T[] needle) {
    int foundCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= hayStack.length - needle.length; i++) {
        boolean found = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < needle.length; j++) {
            if (!Objects.equals(hayStack[i + j], needle[j])) {
                found = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            foundCount++;
        }
    }
    return foundCount;
}
```

And here's a test class to go with it:

```
public class ArrayzTest {

    @Test
    public void countOccurrences_whenNeedleEmpty_returnsHaystackLength(){
        assertThat(Arrayz.countOccurrences(hayStack(), emptyArray()), is(hayStack().length));
    }
    @Test
    public void countOccurrences_whenHaystackEmpty_returnsZero(){
        assertThat(Arrayz.countOccurrences(emptyArray(), hayStack()), is(0));
    }
    @Test
    public void countOccurrences_whenHaystackHasNeedles_countsOccurrences(){
        assertThat(Arrayz.countOccurrences(hayStack(), needle()), is(3));
    }

    private Integer[] needle() {
        return new Integer[]{1,2,3};
    }

    private Integer[] hayStack() {
        return new Integer[]{1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3};
    }

    private Integer[] emptyArray() {
        return new Integer[0];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! this makes a lot of sense