# How to intersect two sorted arrays the fastest possible way?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, merge

I have two huge sorted arrays (~100K items each). I need to intersect them **really fast**. Now I am doing it the standard way:

- if a[i] < b[j] then i++
- if a[i] > b[j] then j++
- else: add a[i] to intersection, i++, j++

But it takes too long (~ 350 microseconds) to complete, which results in quite poor overall performance. Is there a way to do it quicker?

**P.S.** Intersection size is not larger that 1000 items (on average) and I need only 25 to 100 of them.

Comment: Regarding the intersection, if an item appears in both array a and array b does it appear in the result once or twice?

Comment: Do you need to *merge* the arrays or just to compute their intersection?

Comment: If you need 25, the stop after 25.

Comment: are you receiving them sorted or unsorted?

Comment: @mba12 Treat arrays as sorted sets (no duplicates guaranteed). The resulting array is sorted set also.

Comment: @rici Totally sorry, was asking about intersection.

Comment: As Tamas Hegedus noted, if you only the first 100 or so values, then just merge the first hundred from both the sorted sub-lists. You will need max 200 additional space. No need to consider the rest.

Comment: Also in the else part you are incrementing both `i` and `j` shouldn't you increment only one at a time?

Comment: @efekctive They are **sorted!** and it's the key point.

Comment: @RavindraHV Not quite. If algorithm encounters a match you can say that it extracts item from both arrays (thus both indices are getting incremented).

Comment: The intersection of 100K elements is going to take some time, the best way to speed it up is to not do this and find another way to solve your problem e.g. use a BitSet instead to find an intersection. (or stop once you have enough values)

Comment: Deleted my comment. I ran some numbers and it does not work

Comment: These are arrays of ints?

Comment: @displayName Not specified, but it looks like he's doing comparisons in 5-10 clock cycles.  So strings are probably unlikely...

Comment: @btilly: If we know what data type it is and/or what is the range of values, there may be a better solution.

Comment: Are you sure you were talking about microseconds, not milliseconds? Because 350 microseconds is generally considered fast(== 0.35 milliseconds)

Answer (score 2):

Running through 2 100k arrays in parallel requires about 200k comparisons.  You are currently completing it in 350 microseconds = 350k nanoseconds.  So your per comparison time is just under 2 nanoseconds.  If your CPU is around 4 GHz, then that's 8 clock cycles.

That's good.  You could try to be sophisticated, detecting runs and so on, but probably you'll hurt yourself more with pipeline stalls than you'll save work.

There are only 2 ways to speed this up.  Do less work, or add more workers.

You've indicating that doing less work is feasible, which is why Tamas Hegedus suggested that.  Instead of creating the intersection, create an `Iterator` that will return the next thing in the intersection.  This will require you to rewrite the logic that uses said iterator, but you'll do under 10% of the current computation.  Which is going to be close to 10x faster.

As for adding workers, you'll want to divide the work among worker threads and keep them from stepping all over each other.  For `k` small (no larger than your number of CPUs!), with a logarithmic amount of work in the size of your arrays, you can do a quickselect to find `k-1` values that break the combined arrays into `k` even chunks (**oops** Adapt http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/ instead of doing a quickselect...), and the indexes of those values in each array.  This creates `k` problems of even difficulty, each of which can be specified as 4 numbers.  Spin up `k` threads and let each get a chunk of the answer.  This will be roughly `k` times faster than what you are currently doing.

At the cost of a *lot* more effort, these approaches can be combined.  What you do is have the iterator create, say, 4 workers and hand out blocks to each.  When you call `iter.next()` the iterator will hand you a next value that it has if it has one.  If it doesn't have one it will wait for the worker that is producing its next block to complete, grab that block, hand that worker another block if one is ready, and then hand out the first value in that block.  You can play with the block size.  You want it large enough that the CPU does a good job of figuring out that it should be streaming from RAM to CPU caches, and doesn't think that there is synchronization contention between threads.

My guess given the size and synchronization constraints, the hybrid approach won't be much of a win, if any, over the iterator approach.  But if you're really desperate, you can try it.

Comment: The arrays are sorted so quickselect is not really what is needed. You need a variant on the standard "median of two sorted lists" algorithm (which is sublinear, so its nicer).

Comment: @rici You're right, I named the wrong thing.  Do you know the right one?  But in context it should be clear, you're just trying to do a search to figure out where to insert a pair of indexes.  As I said, though, the running time is `O(log(n))`.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting a naive implementation of the problem/solutions: 2 arrays filled with random ints. If the threshold of 100 intersected values is reached, the loops break.

One loops using the OP logic. The other launches two threads each one processing one half of the array.

It seems that the threading overhead can be an issue. Or It may need fine tuning.

It is a 20 runs sample. Worst case scenario: no intersection that forces the run to the end of arrays. Times are in microseconds.

```
Workers: 2806
Workers: 4197
Workers: 4235
Workers: 818
Workers: 729
Workers: 3376
Workers: 740
Workers: 688
Workers: 2245
Workers: 732
Workers: 330
Workers: 945
Workers: 605
Workers: 630
Workers: 630
Workers: 334
Workers: 643
Workers: 309
Workers: 290
Workers: 761
done
Sorted: 1525
Sorted: 405
Sorted: 550
Sorted: 880
Sorted: 265
Sorted: 267
Sorted: 252
Sorted: 310
Sorted: 253
Sorted: 272
Sorted: 285
Sorted: 270
Sorted: 270
Sorted: 315
Sorted: 267
Sorted: 269
Sorted: 265
Sorted: 258
Sorted: 269
Sorted: 289
done

package so;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public final class CrazyClass {

    static class Feeder implements Runnable{
        final int b, e;
        int[] k1001;
        int[] k1002;

        final Set<Integer> setThis;

        Feeder(int[] ia, int[] ia1, int be, int en, Set<Integer> s){
            k1001 = ia;
            k1002= ia1;
            b = be;
            e = en;
            setThis = s;
        }

        public void run() {
            int i2 = b;
            for(int i1 = b; i1 < e; i1++){
                if (k1001[i1] == k1002[i2]){
                    synchronized(setThis){
                        setThis.add(k1001[i1]);
                        if (setThis.size() == 25){
                            System.out.println("bye!!!");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (k1001[i1] < k1002[i2])
                    i1++;
                else if (k1001[i1] > k1002[i2])
                    i2++;
            }

        }
    }

    static void sorted(){
        int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
        Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Random r = new Random();
        int[] k1001 = new int[100000];
        int[] k1002 = new int[100000];

        for(int i = 0; i< k1001.length; i++){
            k1001[i] = r.nextInt();
            k1002[i] = r.nextInt();
        }

        Arrays.sort(k1001);
        Arrays.sort(k1002);

        long l = System.nanoTime();

        for(; i1 < k1001.length; i1++){
            if (k1001[i1] == k1002[i2]){
                result.add(k1001[i1]);
                if (result.size() == 100){
                    System.out.println("bye!!!");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (k1001[i1] < k1002[i2])
                i1++;
            else if (k1001[i1] > k1002[i2])
                i2++;
        }
        l = System.nanoTime() - l;
        System.out.println("Sorted: " + TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.convert(l, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
    }

    static void workers(){
        Thread t1, t2;
        Set<Integer> setThis = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Random r = new Random();
        int[] k1001 = new int[100000];
        int[] k1002 = new int[100000];

        for(int i = 0; i< k1001.length; i++){
            k1001[i] = r.nextInt();
            k1002[i] = r.nextInt();
        }

        t1 = new Thread(new Feeder(k1001, k1002, 0, 49999, setThis));
        t2 = new Thread(new Feeder(k1001, k1002, 50000, 99999, setThis));
        try{
            long l = System.nanoTime();
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            System.out.println("Workers: " + TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.convert(System.nanoTime() - l, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));

        }catch(Exception x){

        }
    }

    static public void main(String[] args){
        int run = 20;
        for(int i = 0; i < run; i++)
            workers();
        System.out.println("done");
        for(int i = 0; i < run; i++)
            sorted();
        System.out.println("done");

    }
}
```

Comment: To reduce thread overhead, each thread should read from separate parts of the array, and should write to different places.  That way memory does not need to be synchronized between CPUs.

Comment: Well, one thread reads below 50000 the other above. You can write the intersection in two places but at some point the check for 100 needs to happen so synchronization needs to happen. It is 3 times what the current count of microseconds is. The OP could check using a ThreadPool and maybe more threads can absorb their costs and some more

Comment: I think the bigger problem is that 100K is not that much given current state of hardware and jvm

Comment: How does the second worker figure out where to start in the second array?  It looks to me like it has to scan through 50k values first.  Values that are being accessed by the first thread.  It also looks like you might have one stopping at 25 and the other processing its whole half.  If so that will hurt time.  Plus you're adding time to start 2 threads.  If he has many of these problems, having dedicated worker threads could save that.

Comment: If you have numbers show them. Modify my code to show your idea yields a better throughput than 350 microseconds. Help the OP

Comment: I don't have a Java environment set up.  But change `if (setThis.size() == 25){` to if (24 < setThis.size()){` and add in a binary search for the right start index in the second array and see what happens.

Comment: Set it up and try it. But please explain what the binary search is for on the right. What is it going to look for?

Comment: It is going to look for the first index in `k1002` whose value is equal to or larger than the value of `k1001[i1]`.

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem, But I may be wrong and as I said, set it up, grab my silly code, modify it to your specs, and run it. If your solution results in less microseconds than the OP algorithm post it. Logging off

Answer (score 0):

Below code runs within around 10 millis for me. So I guess you are either processing strings or on a scripting language.

```
package com.example.so.algorithms;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * <p> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538902/how-to-intersect-two-sorted-arrays-the-fastest-possible-way#comment72213844_42538902 </p>
 * <p> Given two sorted sub-lists of 100k each determine the first 10 intersecting (common) entries within 350 millis </p>
 * @author Ravindra
 * @since 03March2017
 *
 */
public class TestMergeIntersection {

    /**
     * <pre>
Time (millis):9
Result :[442958664, 932132404, 988442487, 1356502780, 1614742980, 1923995812, 1985016181, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    </pre>
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        handleTest();
    }

    private static void handleTest() {
        int size = 1024*128;
        int intersectionCount = 100;
        int[] arrayOne = generateSortedSublist(size);
        int[] arrayTwo = generateSortedSublist(size);
        int[] result = new int[intersectionCount];
        int count = 0;
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(count < 100 && i < size && j < size ) {
            if( arrayOne[i] < arrayTwo[j]) {
                i++;
            } else if(  arrayOne[i] > arrayTwo[j] ) {
                j++;
            } else {
                result[count] =arrayOne[i]; 
                i++;
                j++;
                count++;
            }
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Time (millis):"+(end-start));
        System.out.println("Result :"+Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    private static int[] generateSortedSublist(int size) {

        Random random = new Random();
        int[] result = new int[size];

        for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
            result[i] = random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        Arrays.sort(result);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think OP were talking about microseconds, and you are talking about milliseconds. 10 mils = 10000 mics > 350 mics