# What is the fastest way to intersect two large set of ids

Tags: algorithm, assembly, neural-network, gpu, bigdata

## The Problem

On a server, I host ids in a json file. From clients, I need to mandate the server to intersect and sometimes negate these ids (the ids never travel to the client even though the client instructs the server its operations to perform).

I typically have 1000's of ids, often have 100,000's of ids, and have a maximum of 56,000,000 of them, where each value is unique and between -100,000,000 and +100,000,000.

These ids files are stable and do not change (so it is possible to generate a different representation for it that is better adapted for the calculations if needed).

[Sample ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LHHN.png)

[Largest file sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DFjU.png)

I need an algorithm that will intersect ids in the sub-second range for most cases. What would you suggest? I code in java, but do not limit myself to java for the resolution of this problem (I could use JNI to bridge to native language).

## Potential solutions to consider

Although you could not limit yourselves to the following list of broad considerations for solutions, here is a list of what I internally debated to resolve the situation.

- **Neural-Network pre-qualifier:** Train a neural-network for each ids list that accepts another list of ids to score its intersection potential (0 means definitely no intersection, 1 means definitely there is an intersection). Since neural networks are good and efficient at pattern recognition, I am thinking of pre-qualifying a more time-consuming algorithm behind it.
- **Assembly-language:** On a Linux server, code an assembly module that does such algorithm. I know that assembly is a mess to maintain and code, but sometimes one need the speed of an highly optimized algorithm without the overhead of a higher-level compiler. Maybe this use-case is simple enough to benefit from an assembly language routine to be executed directly on the Linux server (and then I'd always pay attention to stick with the same processor to avoid having to re-write this too often)? Or, alternately, maybe C would be close enough to assembly to produce clean and optimized assembly code without the overhead to maintain assembly code.
- **Images and GPU:** GPU and image processing could be used and instead of comparing ids, I could BITAND images. That is, I create a B&W image of each ids list. Since each id have unique values between -100,000,000 and +100,000,000 (where a maximum of 56,000,000 of them are used), the image would be mostly black, but the pixel would become white if the corresponding id is set. Then, instead of keeping the list of ids, I'd keep the images, and do a BITAND operation on both images to intersect them. This may be fast indeed, but then to translate the resulting image back to ids may be the bottleneck. Also, each image could be significantly large (maybe too large for this to be a viable solution). An estimate of a 200,000,000 bits sequence is 23MB each, just loading this in memory is quite demanding.
- **String-matching algorithms:** String comparisons have many adapted algorithms that are typically extremely efficient at their task. Create a binary file for each ids set. Each id would be 4 bytes long. The corresponding binary file would have each and every id sequenced as their 4 bytes equivalent into it. The algorithm could then be to process the smallest file to match each 4 bytes sequence as a string into the other file.

Am I missing anything? Any other potential solution? Could any of these approaches be worth diving into them?

I did not yet try anything as I want to secure a strategy before I invest what I believe will be a significant amount of time into this.

***EDIT #1:***

Could the solution be a map of hashes for each sector in the list? If the information is structured in such a way that each id resides within its corresponding hash key, then, the smaller of the ids set could be sequentially ran and matching the id into the larger ids set first would require hashing the value to match, and then sequentially matching of the corresponding ids into that key match?

This should make the algorithm an O(n) time based one, and since I'd pick the smallest ids set to be the sequentially ran one, n is small. Does that make sense? Is that the solution?

Something like this (where the H entry is the hash):

{
"H780" : [ 45902780, 46062780, -42912780, -19812780, 25323780, 40572780, -30131780, 60266780, -26203780, 46152780, 67216780, 71666780, -67146780, 46162780, 67226780, 67781780, -47021780, 46122780, 19973780, 22113780, 67876780, 42692780, -18473780, 30993780, 67711780, 67791780, -44036780, -45904780, -42142780, 18703780, 60276780, 46182780, 63600780, 63680780, -70486780, -68290780, -18493780, -68210780, 67731780, 46092780, 63450780, 30074780, 24772780, -26483780, 68371780, -18483780, 18723780, -29834780, 46202780, 67821780, 29594780, 46082780, 44632780, -68406780, -68310780, -44056780, 67751780, 45912780, 40842780, 44642780, 18743780, -68220780, -44066780, 46142780, -26193780, 67681780, 46222780, 67761780 ],
"H782" : [ 27343782, 67456782, 18693782, 43322782, -37832782, 46152782, 19113782, -68411782, 18763782, 67466782, -68400782, -68320782, 34031782, 45056782, -26713782, -61776782, 67791782, 44176782, -44096782, 34041782, -39324782, -21873782, 67961782, 18703782, 44186782, -31143782, 67721782, -68340782, 36103782, 19143782, 19223782, 31711782, 66350782, 43362782, 18733782, -29233782, 67811782, -44076782, -19623782, -68290782, 31721782, 19233782, 65726782, 27313782, 43352782, -68280782, 67346782, -44086782, 67741782, -19203782, -19363782, 29583782, 67911782, 67751782, 26663782, -67910782, 19213782, 45992782, -17201782, 43372782, -19992782, -44066782, 46142782, 29993782 ],
"H540" : [...

Comment: Could you explain what "intersect" means in this context?  Perhaps pseudo code for a very simple implementation of the operation you desire could be helpful.

Comment: This might be a case where a Bloom Filter would be a useful preprocessing step.

Comment: Are the ID sets dense?  Are the IDs random?

Comment: @fuz : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection

Comment: @TomV I have considered that it could mean “intersection of ID sets,” but it could've also meant something else.

Comment: "Intersect" means that an id value resides in both sets.

Comment: The ids may appear random to the outside eye, yet they are not. I feel I've said too much or not enough about the ids here, so let me expand on what they are:

I divide earth into 10,000 sections of latitude, 10,000 sections of longitude, that results into 100,000,000 sectors. Ids are assigned for sectors that are not purely water, that is about 28% of earth (with some distortion because of sectors that are far from the equator). That then means 28,000,000 ids on a potential 100,000,000. The beauty of these ids is that I can geolocate them in a heartbeat from their value.

Comment: For the negative values, I offset 1/2 a degree of latitude and 1/2 degree of longitude and perform the same operation and negate the value (negative ids). That allows me to handle limit cases within the same sector. These are for ids [-100,000,000,-1]. Once again, there will be only about 28% of them that is not water. That then sums-up to 56,000,000 ids that can range anywhere from -100,000,000 to 100,000,000.

Comment: I imported a database of all geolocated points in the world (7 billion points) that are efficiently indexed. For example, someone may be interested in a place close to the beach, an opera, and that has high density of hiking trails (I have 600+ categories). Each of these criteria is an id set, intersecting them (all 3 of them) are the sectors the person want. I need this process to be efficient.

Comment: How about *leave it to a standard DB engine*? (See also: [How to intersect two sorted arrays the fastest possible way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42538902/3789665).)

Comment: That would seem to make sense (using a DB engine), but my process needs to be distributed, highly available and the boot time needs to be close to zero. I am almost only left with file manipulations as a result of these constraints.

Comment: Have you tried using a GIS or similar database system optimised for this use case?  R-trees and similar data structures where specifically designed to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: I will research this indeed. Thanks for the tip (R-trees).

Comment: @PhilippeRoy If that's what you need, just use a GIS.  There's zero need to roll your own.

Comment: @fuz I hear you, but my world is not as simple. I do distributed GIS operations on a server. GIS systems are typically collocated, not distributed. In complexity comes opportunity for the adapted use-cases. With my unique architecture, I am now able to display handle millions of markers in a browser (where the typical limit is at about 6,000 for clients). Now I am pushing the envelope to also match 7 billions qualified markers to be searched against in the sub-second range response. No client can do that (this is why Google just displays stupid icons on the map, and it is not searchable).

Comment: @fuz After further investigation, R-Tree doesn't cut it. It was a nice recommendation, but in my case I do not have included areas (none of my sectors includes another), as such, an R-Tree is not appropriate. Thanks for the tip though, I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert each file (list of ids) into a bit-array of length 200_000_001, where bit at index `j` is set if the list contains value `j-100_000_000`. It is possible, because the range of id values is fixed and small.

Then you can simply use bitwise `and` and `not` operations to intersect and negate lists of ids. Depending on the language and libraries used, it would require operating element-wise: iterating over arrays and applying corresponding operations to each index.

Finally, you should measure your performance and decide whether you need to do some optimizations, such as parallelizing operations (you can work on different parts of arrays on different processors), preloading some of arrays (or all of them) into memory, using GPU, etc.

Comment: If you implement this in Fortran, C or C++, it'll likely auto-vectorise pretty well.

Comment: For negation, it might be useful to store the IDs interleaved: 8 positive IDs followed by 8 negative IDs.  You can then match against the negated IDs by byte-swapping one of the sets on the fly.

Comment: With this approach, each file size would be 200,000,000 / 8 bytes = 23MB. I figure that loading both files in memory (46MB) to then perform the bitwise operations may kill my budget of time. Also, once the operation was done, I still need to reiterate to build the resulting set of intersecting ids. Am I missing something or this is not my Holly-Grail for this problem? Does that make sense?

Comment: `this is not my Holly-Grail for this problem?` Not with `[typically] 1000's of [unique IDs out of] -100,000,000 and +100,000,000, but a pretty good bet at `56,000,000`.

Comment: @PhilippeRoy: With your typical set size being only in the 1000s, a bitmap is pretty sparse most of the time so yeah, this will cost a lot of cache footprint / memory bandwidth ANDing zeros.  As greybeard says, a bitset is great for large sets, when it's pretty dense.

Comment: @PhilippeRoy: BTW, you can iterate fairly efficiently over set bits in a bit-array (searching for position of next `1`, e.g. inside a chunk doing `x &= x-1` (clear lowest set bit) / `pos = base + std::countr_zero( x );` or the Java equivalent).  So for large-enough sets, you can just keep them as bitmaps, not converting back to larger arrays of integers.  So you might consider having two different strategies / storage-formats.  Intersecting a shortish list of integers with a bitset is just a matter of iterating over the integers and checking the bitset at each position.

Comment: @PhilippeRoy: zip (or much better, zstd) of a binary bitmap could make it small and fast to load even if sparse, although it still sucks for cache footprint.  Or int32 little-endian binary integer list files will also be faster to load than JSON text, if getting data from files is a real performance concern.  (A file format that records the endianness, and some functionality to dump / reload to text, will ensure portability.)

Comment: @peterCordes It is a nice tip to zip these huge files indeed. This would alleviate the disk storage issue. But, it won't alleviate the memory issue once unzipped. I am working on an algorithmic solution for my problem that does not involve bitmaps right now, but it would be nice to compare and benchmark both solutions if I can get to this. Thank you for all the nice feedback on the problem I exposed. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

First, the bitmap approach will produce the required performance, at a huge overhead in memory.  You'll need to benchmark it, but I'd expect times of maybe 0.2 seconds, with that almost entirely dominated by the cost of loading data from disk, and then reading the result.

However there is another approach that is worth considering.  It will use less memory most of the time.  For most of the files that you state, it will perform well.

First let's use [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org/) for a file format.  The type can be something like this:

```
struct Ids {
    is_negated @0 :Bool;
    ids @1 :List(Int32);
}
```

The key is that ids are always kept *sorted*.  So list operations are a question of running through them in parallel.  And now:

- Applying `not` is just flipping `is_negated`.
- If neither is negated, it is a question of finding IDs in both lists.
- If the first is not negated and the second is, you just want to find IDs in the first that are not in the second.
- If the first is negated and the second is not, you just want to find IDs in the second that are not in the first.
- If both are negated, you just want to find all ids in either list.

If your list has 100k entries, then the file will be about 400k.  A `not` requires copying 400k of data (very fast).  And intersecting with another list of the same size involves 200k comparisons.  Integer comparisons complete in a clock cycle, and branch mispredictions take something like 10-20 clock cycles.  So you should be able to do this operation in the 0-2 millisecond range.

Your worst case 56,000,000 file will take over 200 MB and intersecting 2 of them can take around 200 million operations.  This is in the 0-2 second range.

For the 56 million file and a 10k file, your time is almost all spent on numbers in the 56 million file and not in the 10k one.  You can speed that up by adding a "galloping" mode where you do a binary search forward in the larger file looking for the next matching number and picking most of them.  Do be warned that this code tends to be tricky and involves lots of mispredictions.  You'll have to benchmark it to find out how big a size difference is needed.

In general this approach will lose for your very biggest files.  But it will be a huge win for most of the sizes of file that you've talked about.

Comment: To structure a negation rather than to process a negation is a good idea that can improve performance indeed. I will factor-in some elements to that regard in my final solution. Thank you for the tip.