# Big theta notation of insertion sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, insertion-sort, big-o

I'm studying asymptotic notations from the book and I can't understand what the author means. I know that `if f(n) = Θ(n^2) then f(n) = O(n^2)`. However, I understand from the author's words that for insertion sort function algorithm `f(n) = Θ(n)` and `f(n)=O(n^2)`.

Why? Does the big omega or big theta change with different inputs?

He says that:

> "The Θ(n^2) bound on the worst-case running time of insertion sort, however, does not imply a Θ(n^2) bound on the running time of insertion sort on every input. "

However it is different for big-oh notation. What does he mean? What is the difference between them?

I'm so confused. I'm copy pasting it below:

> Since O-notation describes an upper bound, when we use it to bound the worst-case running
>   time of an algorithm, we have a bound on the running time of the algorithm on every input.
>   Thus, the O(n^2) bound on worst-case running time of insertion sort also applies to its running
>   time on every input. The Θ(n^2) bound on the worst-case running time of insertion sort,
>   however, does not imply a Θ(n^2) bound on the running time of insertion sort on every input.
>   For example, when the input is already sorted, insertion sort runs in
>   Θ(n) time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the big omega or big theta change with different inputs?

Yes. To give a simpler example, consider linear search in an array from left to right. In the worst and average case, this algorithm takes f(*n*) = *a* × *n*/2 + *b* expected steps for some constants *a* and *b*. But when the left element is guaranteed to always hold the key you're looking for, it always takes *a* + *b* steps.

Since Θ denotes a strict bound, and Θ(*n*) != Θ(*n*²), it follows that the Θ for the two kinds of input is different.

**EDIT**: as for Θ and big-O being different on the same input, yes, that's perfectly possible. Consider the following (admittedly trivial) example.

When we set *n* to 5, then *n* = 5 and *n* < 6 are both true. But when we set *n* to 1, then *n* = 5 is false while *n* < 6 is still true.

Similarly, big-O is just an upper bound, just like < on numbers, while Θ is a strict bound like =.

(Actually, Θ is more like *a* < *n* < *b* for constants *a* and *b*, i.e. it defines something analogous to a range of numbers, but the principle is the same.)

Comment: For a same function and same input , is it possible that the big-oh and big-theta is different?

Comment: To elaborate, `Theta(f(n))` is actually the *intersection* of `O(f(n))` and `Omega(f(n))`. Everything that is `Theta(f(n))` is also `O(f(n))` - but not the other way around.

Comment: in the link which David gave , a man says that : " Basically when we say an algorithm is of O(n), it's also O(n^2), O(n^1000000), O(2^n), ... but a Θ(n) algorithm is not Θ(n^2). "  can this sentence be the exact answer of my question ? "O(n^2) applies to every answer" author says.  Even if the best case is f(n)=O(1) , we can say f(n)=O(n^2) because worst case is O(n^2). However , since theta(n) is not theta(n^2) , we cannot say the same thing for theta unlike in big-og notation.  Am i right?

Comment: @user1308990: no. Θ vs. O is completely unrelated to best case vs. expected vs. worst case. You can say f(n) = O(1) even when f(n) = O(n²) just because n² > 1 for every n greater than some constant.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to CLRS edition 3
 Page -44(Asymptotic notation,functions,and running times)
It says -

Even when we use asymptotic notation to apply to the running time of an algorithm, `we need to understand which running time we mean`. Sometimes we are interested in the `worst-case` running time. `Often, however, we wish to characterize the running time no matter what the input. In other words, we often wish to make a blanket statement that covers all inputs, not just the worst case.`

Takings from the above para:

- Worst case provides the atmost limit for the running time of an algorithm.
  Thus, the O(n^2)  bound on worst-case running time of insertion sort also applies to its running time on every input.
- But `Theta(n^2)` bound on the worst-case running time of insertion sort, however, does not imply   `Theta(n^2)`  bound on the running time of insertion sort on every input.
  Because best case running time of insertion sort yields `Theta(n)`.(When the list is already sorted)
- We usually write the `worst case` time complexity of an algorithm but when best case and average case come into accountability the time complexity varies according to these cases.

Answer (score 0):

> In simple words, the running time of a programs is described as a
> function of its input size i.e. f(n).

The `=` is asymmetric, thus an+b=O(n) means f(n) belongs to set O(g(n)). So we can also say an+b=O(n^2) and its true because f(n) for some value of a,b and n belongs to set O(n^2).

Thus Big-Oh(O) only gives an upper bound or you can say the notation gives a `blanket statement`, which means all the inputs of a given input size are covered not just the worst case once. For example in case of insertion sort an array of size n in reverse order.

So n=O(n^2) is true but will be an abuse when defining worst case running time for an algorithm. As worst case running time gives an upper bound on the running time for any **input**. And as we all know that in case of insertion sort the running time will depend upon how the much sorted the input is in the given array of a fixed size. So if the array is sort the running will be linear.

So we need a tight asymptotic bound notation to describe our worst case,
which is provided by Θ notation thus the worst case of insertion sort will be Θ(n^2) and best case will be Θ(n).

Answer (score -1):

> we have a bound on the running time of the algorithm on every input

It means that if there is a set of inputs with running time `n^2` while other have less, then the algorithm is `O(n^2)`.

> The Θ(n^2) bound on the worst-case running time of insertion sort,
>   however, does not imply a Θ(n^2) bound on the running time of
>   insertion sort on every input

He is saying that the converse is not true. If an algorithm is `O(n^2)`, it doesnt not mean every single input will run with quadratic time.

Comment: Big-O is not the same as "worst case" as you are implying. If there is a set of inputs with running time n^2 while others have less, then the algorithm takes O(n^2) and Theta(n^2) *in the worst case*. Just saying "the algorithm is O(n^2)" is meaningless.

Comment: It *is* Theta(n^2) in the worst case. If you are looking at the worst case than the other cases aren't a factor. Even the part quoted from the book by the OP gives an example of exactly such a case.

Comment: "Theta(n^2) in the worst case" implies the complexity for any input in worst case is quadratic, no less and no more.

Comment: remember, in my word i never talked about worst case or average case or best case, i talked about running time. So I am not mixing Big-O and worse case.

Answer (score -4):

My academic theory on the insertion sort algorithm is far away in the past, but from what I understand in your copy-paste :

big-O notation always describe the worst case, but big-Theta describe some sort of average for typical data.

take a look at this : [What is the difference between Θ(n) and O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-on)

Comment: Nope, that's not what Θ and big-O mean. Θ is a strict bound, O an upper bound. Both can be applied to average, worst-case, best-case or amortized analysis.