# Analyzing complexity for a code fragment

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Let A be an array[1..n] which has zeros and ones in it.and **func()** be function whose complexity is theta(m).For the given pseudo code what would be the complexity?

```
  counter=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
          if(a[i]==1)
           counter++;
         else
           func();
   }
```

Accorlding to me the worst case for the function func() to be called at most n times would be when the arrays are completly filled with zeroes .
Hence as the theta noation of func() is given as theta(m)

The complexity for the above code would be :theta(mn) ....??? If no,please help me with a proper validation.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of the above code will be **O(mn) (Big O mn)**.
**Why?**
func() as you say is theta(m)
Now when calculating the time complexity, as you noted yourself, the **worst** case when **func is called n times** would result in O(mn).
**Why not Theta(mn)**?
Theta is a tighter bound  on the time complexity. It not only means that it will always performs at worst mn* but also that at best mn* (*give or take a multiplicative or additive constant). So it increases proportionally with the input. However we cannot guarantee a lower bound(a.k.a omega) of omega(mn).
[Go here to find more information on big O vs vs Big Theta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/471206/1675971)

And you should be able to answer why we cannot gauarantee a lower bound of Theta(mn) yourself.

Best, Digvijay

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong if   omega of f() is (ab) and big O of f() is (ab) ,then  theta of f() is (ab) ??

Comment: Yes you are right in essence (and wrong in the language). When writing it is written as f is omega(ab), f is O(ab), and not like "omega of f" or "big O of f".

Comment: Consider marking the question solved, if your question has been answered.