# More functional way to do this?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript

[This](http://pizzaforthought.blogspot.in/2014/05/and-infinity-beyond.html) post of mine discusses Thomson's paradox, and simulates it in Clojure.
The `state` function returns the state of the lamp at time = t.

```
(defn thomsons-lamp []
  (iterate (fn [[onoff dur]]
             [(not onoff) (/ dur 2)])
           [true 1])) 

(defn state [t]
  (let [t-vals (map second (thomsons-lamp))]
    (loop [i 1]
      (if (<= t (apply + (take i t-vals)))
        ((comp first last) (take i (thomsons-lamp)))
        (recur (inc i))))))
```

How do I define a cleaner `state` function (preferably without loop/recur)?

Comment: That looks like a perfectly fine and functional way of going about this. There is nothing inherently un-functional about loop/recur.

Comment: Well, the second function has unnecessarily quadratic complexity. It could be written fairly cleanly using reduce/reduced.

Comment: More than a year ago, I came across your post and glanced over it briefly, with the intention to go through it more closely later. When I went back to find it, later, however, I could not remember the name of the paradox. No amount of googling got me anywhere. Today, I coincidentally came across the name Thomson's Lamp in a VSauce video on YouTube and googled "Thomson's Lamp Clojure", which brought me here!

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me by answering this: Since the experiment of switching the light leads to an infinite non-convergent mathematical series, how could a program simulate it? I am assuming that this is what you code do, I have no knowledge of functional programming. Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance the `iterate` function returns a lazy list, ie, a list whose elements are computed on demand. The code says how to generate the nth element, but a particular element is computed only when someone tries to access it.

Comment: @divs1210, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only sins here are

- Unnecessary quadratic complexity in `state`
- Evidence of floating point usage and error in your blog post. The code as written should be using ratios -- (state 2) should not terminate...

Reduce/reduced would be a good candidate for your `state` function.

```
(defn thomsons-lamp []
  (map vector (iterate not true) (iterate #(* 1/2 %) 1)))

(defn state [t]
  (reduce (fn [[s1 t1] [s2 t2]] 
            (if (>= t1 t) (reduced s1) [s2 (+ t1 t2)]))
          (thomsons-lamp)))
```

Comment: Regarding second bullet, I reckon you are using ClojureScript, eh?

Comment: ClojureScript, yes. In fact, it is awesome how easy it is to work on such a high level language in just your browser, without setting up any environment whatsoever. I knew the ratio/floating-point thing was causing a problem, but didn't care enough. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

**A one-line solution in Clojure**

In Clojure, though not in ClojureScript, we can express the `state` function as a series of pure function applications:

```
(defn state [t]
  (-> t rationalize / biginteger .bitLength odd?))
```

or, without using the threading macro

```
(defn state [t]
  (odd? (.bitLength (biginteger (/ (rationalize t))))))
```

Let's test it:

```
(map (juxt identity state) [1 0.7 0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2])
; ([1 true] [0.7 true] [0.5 false] [0.4 false] [0.3 false] [0.2 true])
```

Taking it step by step:

```
(defn state [t]
  (-> t
      rationalize ; convert to a ratio to avoid losing precision using floating point
      /           ; take the reciprocal
      biginteger  ; round down (if need be) to a java.math.BigInteger 
      .bitLength  ; take its length in bits (a method, not a Clojure function)
      odd?        ; ask whether odd
      ))
```

**How does it work?**

Instead of testing where the given number `t` fits in the series of toggle-points

```
1 1/2 1/4 1/8 ...
```

we test where `1/t` (that's `(/ t)` in Clojure) fits in the series of inverted toggle-points

```
1 2 4 8 ...
```

which, in binary, is

```
1 10 100 1000 ...
```

which are the smallest numbers with

```
1 2 3 4 ...
```

binary digits.

Applying `BigInteger/bitLength` tells us how many binary digits `1/t` has - rounding down has no effect. This is the number of terms of series `1 2 4 8 ...` that `1/t` reaches. So the answer is whether this number is odd.

Comment: Brilliant solution! Made my day!

Comment: @divs1210 Thanks. I'm not sure that this solution is any faster in a [big theta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-on) sense, but its constants are going to be a lot better - and it was fun to do.