# What does the 'reduced' function do and how to use it

Tags: clojure, reduce

In the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415815/more-functional-way-to-do-this) the responder uses the function [reduced](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reduced)

```
(defn state [t]
  (reduce (fn [[s1 t1] [s2 t2]] 
            (if (>= t1 t) (**reduced** s1) [s2 (+ t1 t2)]))
          (thomsons-lamp)))
```

I looked at the doc and source and can't fully grok it.

```
(defn reduced
  "Wraps x in a way such that a reduce will terminate with the value x"
  {:added "1.5"}
  [x]
  (clojure.lang.Reduced. x))
```

In the example above I think `(reduced s1)` is supposed to end the reduction and return s1.

Is using reduce + reduced equivalent to hypothetical reduce-while or reduce-until functions if either existed?

Comment: The source for `reduced` doesn't tell you a whole lot - you have to look at the source for `reduce` to really know what's going on.

Comment: Even the source to `reduce` calls out to some implementation methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reduced provides a way to break out of a reduce with the value provided.

For example to add the numbers in a sequence

```
(reduce (fn [acc x] (+ acc x)) (range 10))
```

returns 45

```
(reduce (fn [acc x] (if (> acc 20) (reduced "I have seen enough") (+ acc x))) (range 10))
```

returns "I have seen enough"