# In the context of Big O notation, what does asymptotic or asymptotically mean?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am trying to understand the words asymptotic and asymptotically. In other words, what do we really mean by a growth rate f(x)  being ***asymptotically*** greater than, less than, greater than or equal to, less than or equal to g(x) what does **asymptotically** really mean? I am ***not*** looking for a rehash of the question: "What is big O, big Theta and big Omega notation?"; just the meaning of the words asymptotic and asymptotically in this context.

Example:

"**f(x) = O(g(x))** (big-oh) means that the growth rate of f(x) is ***asymptotically*** less than or equal to the growth rate of g(x)."

The above was taken from  this Stack Overflow page: [What is the difference between Θ(n) and O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-%CE%98n-and-on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematically, you can think of the statements f(n) = O(g(n)) and f(n) = Θ(g(n)) as ways of reasoning about the behavior of

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> f(n)/g(n)

Specifically, if f(n) = O(g(n)), then this limit exists and is some finite value, and if f(n) = Θ(g(n)), then this limit exists and its value is nonzero and not infinite. In this sense, "asymptotically" means the same thing as the term "asymptotically" from calculus - we're  reasoning about the behavior of some quantity in the limit.

Formally, the definition of big-O notation involves finding constants c and n<sub>0</sub> with various properties. These properties turn out to be exactly the properties necessary to make the above limit converge to a value under the formal definition of a limit to infinity. It's not often taught this way, but this is mathematically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It means that if you have 'f(x) = O(g(x))', there is an x (x<sub>n</sub>) such that for all values of x such that 'x >= x<sub>n</sub>', f(x) <= C * g(x) (for a constant C larger than 0)'.