# Prove that f(n) = Θ(g(n)) iff g(n) = Θ(f(n))

Tags: algorithm, proof, theorem-proving, big-o

I have been given the problem:

```
f(n) are asymptotically positive functions. Prove f(n) = Θ(g(n)) iff g(n) = Θ(f(n)).
```

Everything I have found points to this statement being invalid. For example an answer I've come across states:

```
f(n) = O(g(n)) implies g(n) = O(f(n))
f(n) = O(g(n)) means g(n) grows faster than f(n). It cannot imply that f(n) grows
faster than g(n). Hence not true.
```

Another states:

```
 If f(n) = O(g(n)) then O(f(n)). This is false. If f(n) = 1 and g(n) = n 
 for all natural numbers n, then f(n) <= g(n) for all natural numbers n, so
 f(n) = O(g(n)). However, suppose g(n) = O(f(n)). Then there are natural
 numbers n0 and a constant c > 0 such that n=g(n) <= cf(n) = c for all n >= 
 n0 which is impossible.
```

I understand that there are slight differences between my exact question and the examples I have found, but I've only been able to come up with solutions that do not prove it. I am correct in thinking that it is not able to be proved or am I looking over some detail?

Comment: O is not the same as Theta. Look up the difference in their meanings

Comment: Note that n = O(n), n = O(n^2), but n^2 != O(n)  ... this simple example can help you to ignore some bad examples( like `f(n) = O(g(n)) implies g(n) = O(f(n))`, which can be true, but only for some particular situations )

Comment: `f(n) = O(g(n)) means g(n) grows faster than f(n)` - wrong. Roughly speaking, it means g grows *at least as fast* as f.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-%CE%98n-and-on

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can start from here:

> Formal Definition: f(n) = Θ (g(n)) means there are positive constants c1, c2, and k, such that 0 ≤ c1g(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ c2g(n) for all n ≥ k.

Because you have that `iff`, you need to start from the left side and to prove the right side, and then start from the right side and prove the left side.

**Left -> right**

We consider that:

```
f(n) = Θ(g(n))
```

and we want to prove that

```
g(n) = Θ(f(n))
```

So, we have some positive constants `c1`, `c2` and `k` such that:

```
0 ≤ c1*g(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ c2*g(n), for all n ≥ k
```

The first relation between `f` and `g` is:

```
c1*g(n) ≤ f(n)     =>     g(n) ≤ 1/c1*f(n)    (1)
```

The second relation between `f` and `g` is:

```
f(n) ≤ c2*g(n)     =>     1/c2*f(n) ≤ g(n)    (2)
```

If we combine `(1)` and `(2)`, we obtain:

```
1/c2*f(n) ≤ g(n) ≤ 1/c1*f(n)
```

If you consider `c3 = 1/c2` and `c4 = 1/c1`, they exist and are positive (because the denominators are positive). And this is true for all `n ≥ k` (where `k` can be the same).

So, we have some positive constants `c3`, `c4`, `k` such that:

```
c3*f(n) ≤ g(n) ≤ c4*f(n), for all n ≥ k
```

which means that `g(n) = Θ(f(n))`.

Analogous for right -> left.