# Big Theta Computation

Tags: java, big-o

Could someone please point me in the right direction for this question?  I need to compute the big theta run time of this function.  I understand that it will run the sum++ (n^2)(n+2) times, but I am unsure how to calculate the big theta for it.  Sorry for a n00b questions, but is it just going to be the highest order?  n^3?

```
for (int i=0; i <= n+2; i++)

   for (int j=0; j < n * n; j++)

      sum++;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can find in the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) Big Theta `f(n) = Θ(g(n))` means that `f` is bounded both above and below by `g` asymptotically. You may also find interesting [Big-θ (Big-Theta) notation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-theta-notation) at Khan Academy. In most *colloquial* cases Big-O and Big-Theta are the same i.e. when someone says about some algorithms Big-O actually Big-Theta is meant. See also [What is the difference between Θ(n) and O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-%CE%98n-and-on) with some examples of differences between Big-O and Big-Theta

And yes, in your case it is OK to just get the highest power of `n`