# Complexity of the python code

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to find the runtime complexity of this Python program. Will the complexity be still n or will it be more than n as I am creating a new list for each recursive call

```
def RecLinearSearch(lyst,number):
    found = False
    index = len(lyst)-1
    if lyst[index] == number:
        found = True
        return found
    elif index<len(lyst)-1:
        index +=1
        return RecLinearSearch(lyst[index:],number)
    return found
print(RecLinearSearch([1,4,5,65,44],55))
```

Comment: Please use code blocks.

Comment: Are you talking about memory or runtime complexity?

Comment: Runtime Complexity

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Nope. It's O(1)

Comment: @EricDuminil whoops. Wasn't reading carefully. Was assuming the function worked as intended...

Comment: Lesson learned from this question: make sure the code does what it is supposed to do before posting. Now *O(1)* is the only correct answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What you just said makes no sense, as linear implies O(n^2).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, if it were working, then why linear?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: It would be `O(n**2)`, I don't see how `lyst[index:]` could be `O(1)`

Comment: @StefanPochmann ... I am [pretty sure linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time) implies O(n) ... ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It *also* implies O(n), yes. But *every linear function is also O(n^2)*.

Comment: @EricDuminil No I didn't.

Comment: That is the exact same question I am trying to ask. Will it be O(n^2) as I am using lyst[index:]

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Okay. Technically, linear is also O(n!) and O(n**n**n**n). It's not very helpful, though.

Comment: Yes, actually I think it's quadratic now. Sorry, it's late where I am. But I'm still not following @StefanPochmann

Comment: @RitikaManwani: You'll have to fix your code first. Right now, it's broken and returns too soon.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Big-O is about upper bounds. If something costs less than $10, it also costs less than $100. What you said is like saying it doesn't cost less than $100 but it does cost less than $10. That's wrong.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: `O()` only gives an information about a maximum boundary, not about a range. If you say you can do the laundry in 2h, it's also technically correct to say you can do it in 6 months.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-%CE%98n-and-on)

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes, I see now.

Comment: @RitikaManwani yeah, use `.pop()` instead so you can scale linearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code was broken. It only required 1 step and checked if the last element is the desired `number`. It was O(1) but didn't do what the function name implies it should do. The recursive call never happened, and the `lyst` was never sliced.

Your updated code runs in O(n**2) : the worst case would be `n` slices at the `n/2`th index on average. It's slower than necessary, and due to the recursive calls, it's not possible to say at which index the number has been found.

If you passed the last index as argument and would leave the `lyst` untouched, it could run in O(n). But then, you also wouldn't need recursive call, just a simple loop.

With a sorted lyst, it could run in O(log n) with a binary search.

Answer (score 5):

Time and space complexity of your function are both **O(1)**, since `index<len(lyst)-1` is always false.