# Algorithm complexity and big O notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I am taking an online class on algorithms and I had the following quiz. I got it wrong and am trying to understand the reason for the answer.

> Which of the following is O(n^3)?
>
> a) 11n + 151 gn + 100
> b) 1/3 n^2
> c) 25000 n^3
> d) All of the above.

The correct answer is (d) all of the above. The reason is that Big-O notation provides only the upper bound on the growth rate of function as n gets large.

I am not sure why the answer is not (c). For example, the upper bound on (b) is less than n^3.

Comment: If something is O(n ^ 2) then it's also O(n ^ 3).

Comment: Upper bound does not necessary mean the *strictest* bound.

Comment: There's no "the" upper bound. There are many upper bounds. The Big-O notation specifies **an** upper bound. A related notation provides *the least* upper bound, but it's not the Big-O notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that *formally*, big-O notation is an asymptotic **upper bound**.

So `1/3*n^2` is `O(n^2)`, but it is also `O(n^3)` and also `O(2^n)`.

While in every-day conversion about complexity  `O(...)` is used as a tight (both upper and lower bound), the theta-notation, or `Θ(...)`  is the technically correct term for this.

For more info see [What is the difference between Θ(n) and O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-%CE%98n-and-on)