# Explain why this time complexity is correct

Tags: time-complexity

Which one is false?

A. log(n^3 * 9^n) is θ(9^n).

B. log(n^5 * 4^(n^2)) is θ(n^2).

C. log(n!) is θ(nlogn).

D. log(n) is θ(logn).

E. cos(3logn^4/19e^n) is θ(1).

I believe it is E is because cosine naturally oscillates. Therefore to say it is tight bounded by O(1) is false. However, the answer is A and I do not understand how they arrived to that conclusion.

This was created by a fellow student for exam preparation and they didn't provide worked-out solutions. Thank you!

Comment: E doesn't say it is bounded by O(1); it says it is θ(1).

Comment: Sorry, typo. However I still don't understand how it is θ(1) as cosine is an oscillating function. Even though it is cos(3logn^4/19e^n).

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/471199/535275