# When something is Big O, does it mean that it is exactly the result of Big O?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

When we say a method has the time complexity of `O(n^2)` is it meant in the same way as in `10^2 = 100` or does it mean that the method is **at max** or **closest** to that notation? I am really confused on how to undertand Big O. I remember something called upper bound, would that mean at max?

Comment: Upperbound can be thought of as a max. Its a way to look at the worst case running time complexity.

Comment: Why not look it up in your favourite [source of information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)?

Comment: I already looked there, and didn't get it. Wikipedia is actually my least favourite source, since I find that they complicate things very much.

Comment: Actually, the Wikipedia explanation is pretty decent if you carefully read through it and take a look at the illustrations. Let me write an answer summarizing what Wikipedia explains.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen All of the notions are *worst case* in a sense that they must fulfill the `forall` operator in the definition. So a single *bad* execution forces the complexity class already. Big-O means that the function isn't *worse* (wrt to asymptotic complexity). Big-Omega means it isn't *better* than. Theta means its in the same complexity class.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen A function being in `O(n^2)` does *not* necessarily mean that it quadruples when the input doubles. `f(n) = n` is still in `O(n^2)`. And even if we were talking Theta, `f(n) = n+1` does not (exactly) quadruple when the input doubles, but is in `Theta(n^2)`. And no, "upper bound" does not mean "worst case". Whether a function represents the best-case, worst-case or average execution time of an algorithm (or something else entirely) is completely independent of whether you use O (upper bound), Omega (lower bound) or Theta (lower and upper bound).

Comment: Their explanation is more than accessible to an average student.  If you don't get it, you *badly* need to brush up your maths.

Comment: @Zabuza Big-O isn't the same as worst-case - linking those two probably leads to more confusion than anything else. [How do O and Ω relate to worst and best case?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23068)

Comment: Related / duplicate: [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/487258) See also: [What is the difference between Θ(n) and O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/471199)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

If a method `f` is inside `O(g)`, with `g` being another function, it means that at some point (exist some `n_0` such that for all `n > n_0`) the function `f` will always output a smaller value than `g` for that point. However, `g` is allowed to have an arbitrary constant `k`. So `f(n) <= k * g(n)` for all `n` above some `n_0`. So `f` is allowed to first be bigger, if it then starts to be smaller and keeps being smaller.

We say *`f` is **asymptotically bounded** by `g`*. *Asymptotically* means that we do not care how `f` behaves in the beginning. Only what it will do when approaching infinity. So we discard all inputs below `n_0`.

---

### Illustration

An illustration would be this:

[image]

The blue function is `k * g` with some constant `k`, the red one is `f`. We see that `f` is greater at first, but then, starting at `x_0`, it will always be smaller than `k * g`. Thus `f in O(g)`.

---

### Definition

Mathematically, this can be expressed by

[image]

which is the usual definition of Big-O. From the explanation above, the definition should be clear. It says that from a certain `n_0` on, the function `f` must be smaller than `k * g` for all inputs. `k` is allowed to be some constant.

*Both images are taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).*

---

### Examples

Here are a couple of examples to familiarize with the definition:

- `n` is in `O(n)` (trivially)
- `n` is in `O(n^2)` (trivially)
- `5n` is in `O(n^2)` (starting from `n_0 = 5`)
- `25n^2` is in `O(n^2)` (taking `k = 25` or greater)
- `2n^2 + 4n + 6` is in `O(n^2)` (take `k = 3`, starting from `n_0 = 5`)

---

### Notes

Actually,`O(g)` is a **set** in the mathematical sense. It contains all functions with the above mentioned property (which are asymptotically bounded by `g`).

So, although some authors write `f = O(g)`, it is actually wrong and should be `f in O(g)`.

There are also other, similar, sets, which only differ in the direction of the bound:

- Big-O: *less equals* `<=`
- Small-o: *less* `<`
- Big-Omega: *greater equals* `>=`
- Small-omega: *greater* `>`
- Theta: Big-O and Big-Omega at the same time (*equals*)

Answer (score 3):

If means that the running time is bounded *above* by N².

More precisely, T(N) < C.N², where C is some constant, and the inequality is true as of a certain N*.

For example, 2N²+4N+6 = O(N²), because 2N²+4N+6 < 3N² for all N>5.