# What is the value of n0?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Just started learning algorithm. But, I don't know what **n0** represent in calculating time complexity.

Full quoto for the mergeSort time complexity.

Ө(nlogn) - C1 * nlogn <= T(n) <= C2 * logn, if n >= **n0**

O(nlogn) - T(n) <= C * nlogn, if n >= **n0**

Comment: Probalby `n0` is the first number where an assymptotically better algorithm is better than its "competitor". But it might be worth to quote the full definition, theorem, etc.

Comment: Sorry, could you simplify what you said? I still don't get it. What is the "first number" is it the first element in an array?

Comment: no the smallest input length. *n* is the length of input.

Comment: I would have expected something like "n >= n0", not like it is quoted here. Is the quote correct?

Comment: @trincot Oh yes, sorry i just realized i typed the quote wrong! I will correct it now.

Comment: It means that the other condition must be true for all *n* above some minimum value *n0*. You can select that value yourself, as long as it makes the statement about *n* true for *all* greater *n*. And of course, if you find a value *n0* with that property, you could also have selected *n[0]+100*, or anything greater.

Comment: @trincot  thanks! now it made sense for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When something is Big O, does it mean that it is exactly the result of Big O?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53240689/when-something-is-big-o-does-it-mean-that-it-is-exactly-the-result-of-big-o)

Answer (score 4):

Intuitively speaking, the statement f(n) = O(g(n)) means

> For any **sufficiently large** value of n, the value of f(n) is bounded from above by a **constant multiple** of g(n).

In other words, although f(n) might initially start off significantly larger than g(n), in the long-run, you'll find that f(n) is eventually matched, or overtaken, by some constant multiple of g(n).

The n<sub>0</sub> you're referring to here is the formal mathematical way of pinning down this idea of "sufficiently large." Specifically, if the claim being made is

> T(n) ≤ C<sub>2</sub> n log n, if n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>,

the value n<sub>0</sub> is some cutoff threshold. That is, it's the point where we say that n is "sufficiently large."

The particular choice of n<sub>0</sub> and C<sub>2</sub> in the above statements will depend on the particular problem that you're working through, but hopefully this gives you a sense of how to interpret what you're looking at.