# what is the worst and best case run time for insertion sort and merge sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Which of these are correct? worst and best case run time for insertion and merge sort?

insertion sort (best case): big O(n) or theta (n)
               (worst case):big O(n^2) or theta (n^2)?

merge sort (best case) : big O(n log n) or theta (n log n)
           (worst case) : big O (n log n) or theta (nlog n)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  As these are well-known metrics, we expect that you can look them up on your own.  Your question doesn't detail where you're stuck on answering these issues.

Comment: read the following:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/471206/56778

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are correct. Good luck