# Usage of Little-O notation

Tags: big-o, little-o

I think understand the principle difference between `big-O` and `little-o` notations. But could anyone tell me why `big-O` is much more popular in practice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Big-O and Little-O Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation)

Answer (score 0):

As @Blender noted in the comments, there is already a long post which includes the answer to this question (and explanation of that answer).  But to boil it down: big-O is easier to prove, and usually good enough.