# Trouble understanding little-o notation example

Tags: algorithm, big-o, notation, asymptotic-complexity, little-o

I'm having trouble with this one problem

```
9n <= cn^3
```

basically I can get down to

```
9/c <= n^2
```

But how do I solve the rest?

Comment: @nabla, It's actually 9n <= o(n^3)

Comment: @Frghtlin Yes reading it again I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

definition of `little o` is

[image]
    we say `f(x)=o(g(x))`.

let f(x)=9*x and g(x)=c*x^3 where c is a positive constant. when x tends to infinity, f(x)/g(x) tends to 0.so we can say `f(x)=o(g(x))`.

asyptotic notations are applicable for  sufficiently large value of n.so for large value of n

```
9n << cn^3
```

for all c>0.

Answer (score -1):

Read this link to undersatnd big-O and little-O [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation)

see in case of your equation, when n=3 it becomes 9*3=23=3^3 so for n<3 9n > n^3. so if you choose c as any number to make 9n<=n^3 for n<3 then it can be in O(n).

Comment: This is not what the OP tries to proof.

Comment: do you mean that it can be in little o(n)?

Comment: @Frigthlin It is O(n), but not o(n).

Comment: @nabla, ah, I'm looking for the little oh, not big oh :(