# if something is little o of f(n) is it also big O of f(n)?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I had a question about Big O vs little o notation. It seems intuitively, that Big O is like <= while little o is like <. Does that mean that if something is little o of f(n), it is also Big O of f(n), in the same way that if i < j, i <= j? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question probably belongs to CS-SE, not SO.

Answer (score 6):

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation). Little-oh implies Big-Oh.

[image: Big o table]

Comment: Wouldn't it be the other way around, that Little-o implies Big-O, as Little-O is strict and Big-O is not? As in, 5 <= 5, but not 5 < 5? Sorry to contradict you if that was a simple typo.

Comment: +1: Though as mentioned it might be good to state explicitly that while little-oh implies big-oh, big-oh does not imply little-oh.

Comment: The "limit definition" doesn't match the usual definition of O. Eg: "f(n) = n if n is even, 0 otherwise" has f(n) <= n, and therefore f = O(n), but lim(f/n) doesn't exist.

Comment: @Anonymous *Technically* there should be a `sup` around the functions in the definition to mean "largest value so far". But you rarely run into functions that keep dipping like your example when analyzing algorithms in practice, and always ignore it when they do, so I use the simplified slightly-wrong definition when explaining.

Comment: @Strilanc counterexamples are the running time of mergesort being O(n log n) and the depth of a perfectly balanced binary tree being O(log n). They don't dip to 0 like the extreme example, but they vary enough that the limits don't exist.

Comment: What is the source of this cheat sheet image?