# Creation of max Heap from stream of integer

Tags: algorithm, heap

Since i know that if there is n element given in array and i want to create a max heap it took **o(n)** because logic is we apply heapify from last parent to root.

But my question is suppose if there is stream of integer is coming and i want to insert element in heap then after inserting n element what will be my time complexity.I think it goes to **o(nlogn)**.

Because for completing each level number of operation will be

> (2^L)*L where L will be depth of tree which will start from zero to ((logn)-1)
>
> Sum=0+1*(2^1)+2*(2^2)...........+(logn-1)(2^(logn-1))

When i did sum of it i got nlogn + constant.So please clarify me what is wrong with it ?

Comment: Did you mean to use big-O notation? [Difference between Big-O and Little-O Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. In the worst case, inserting *n* elements sequentially into a heap will result in *Θ(n log(n))* time.

When the heap has *i* elements, and the *i + 1*-th element is inserted, then at the worst case, it will need to be bubbled up all the way to the top, which is *Θ(log(i))*. Thus the complexity for the sequence of operations, at worst case, is

*∑<sub>i = 1, ..., n</sub>Θ(log(i)) = Θ(log(i!))= Θ(n log(n))*,

where the last part follows from [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).