# What are sublinear algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, limits

I have been asked the following question by one of my fellow mates.

```
Which of the following expressions is not sublinear?
O(log log n)
O(n)
O(logn)
O(root(n))
```

I have gone through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Sub-linear_time but couldn't but I am not sure that I have understood it completely. Could someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hint: sub-linear means that the algorithm scales to be faster than it would if it had linear time complexity

Comment: yet another homework at stackoverflow?

Comment: You can try [Computer Science SO](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) here there are little academic discussions

Comment: @sage444 It's that time of year.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A function, f(x), is said to grow faster than another function, g(x), if the limit of their ratios as x approaches infinity goes to some positive number (or infinity), as seen in the definition below.

[image]

In the case of sublinear, we want to prove that a function grows slower than c*n, where c is some positive number.

Thus, for each function, f(n), in your list, we want the ratio of f(n) to (c*n). If the limit is 0, this means the function, f(n), is sublinear. Otherwise it grows at the same (approximate) speed of n or faster.

```
lim n->inf (log log n)/(c*n) = 0 (via l'Hopital's)
```

**(sublinear)**

```
lim n->inf (n)/(c*n) = 1/c != 0
```

**(linear)**

```
lim n->inf (log n)/(c*n) = 0 (via l'Hopital's)
```

**(sublinear)**

```
lim n->inf (sqrt(n))/(c*n) = 0
```

**(sublinear)**

Comment: If a function grows sublinear, does this imply that sub-additivity holds, too? Or what constraints does the function have to fulfil in addition? I only found the properties for functions over a vector space.

Comment: @AlexVII I hesitate to claim this... but it's quite early and my coffee hasn't kicked in yet. :)

Comment: @erip In the first definition, you mentioned the limit has to be positive bounded. Consider f(x) = x^2 and g(x) = x. f grows faster than g but \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} = \infty is not bounded.

Comment: @ironX that's true, good catch. The ratio doesn't necessarily need to be bounded to grow faster. Will edit.

Answer (score 16):

I think I understood why you're confused: the wikipedia page you link uses [Little-Oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) notation:

> Sub-linear time
>
> An algorithm is said to run in sub-linear time (often spelled sublinear time) if T(n) = o(n)

Beware that T(n) = o(n) is a **stronger** requirement than saying T(n) = O(n).

In particular for a function in O(n) you can't always have the inequality

```
f(x) < k g(x) for all x > a
```

satisfied for every `k` you choose. `y=x` and `k=1` will prove you wrong and little-oh notation requires every `k` to satisfy that expression.

Any O(n) function is **not** also in o(n). Thus your non-sublinear expression is O(n).

I recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1364491/1938163) to continue your studies

Comment: Above line is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Sub-linear_time