# Asymptotic complexity of logarithmic functions

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I know that in terms of complexity, O(logn) is faster than O(n), which is faster than O(nlogn), which is faster than O(n2).
But what about O(n2) and O(n2log), or O(n2.001) and O(n2log):

```
T1(n)=n^2 + n^2logn
```

What is the big Oh and omega of this function? Also, what's little oh?
versus:

```
T2(n)=n^2.001 + n^2logn
```

Is there any difference in big Oh now?
I'm having trouble understanding how to compare logn with powers of n. As in, is logn approximately n^0.000000...1 or n^1.000000...1?

Comment: I think the key point you are missing is this: `log(n)` grows slower than any positive power of `n`, however small that power may be. So `log(n)` isn't approximately *any* power of `n`.

Comment: One thing you can say: `log(n) = n^{o(1)}`. That is, it is asymptotically smaller than `n^{epsilon}` for any `epsilon > 0`.

Answer (score 3):

`O(n^k)` is faster than `O(n^k')` for all `k, k' >= 0` and `k' > k`

`O(n^2)` would be faster than `O(n^2*logn)`

Note that you can only ignore constants, nothing involving the input size can be ignored.

Thus, complexity of `T(n)=n^2 + n^2logn` would be the worse of the two, which is `O(n^2logn)`.

---

Little-oh

Little oh in loose terms is a guaranteed upper bound. Yes, it is called little, and it is more restrictive.

`n^2 = O(n^k)` for **k >= 2** but `n^2 = o(n^k)` for **k > 2**

Practically, it is `Big-Oh` which takes most of the limelight.

---

What about `T(n)= n^2.001 + n^2logn`?

We have n<sup>2.001</sup> = n<sup>2</sup>*n<sup>0.001</sup> and n<sup>2</sup> * log(n).

To settle the question, we need to figure out what would *eventually* be bigger, n<sup>0.001</sup> or log(n).

It turns out that a function of the form n<sup>k</sup> with `k > 0` will eventually take over `log(n)` for a *sufficiently* large `n`.

Same is the case here, and thus `T(n) = O`(n<sup>2.001</sup>`)`.

**Practically though, `log(n)` will be larger than n<sup>0.001</sup>.**

(10<sup>3300</sup>)<sup>0.001</sup> < log(10<sup>3300</sup>) `(1995.6 < 3300)`, and the **sufficiently large n** in this case would be just around 10<sup>3650</sup>, an astronomical number.

Worth mentioning again, **10<sup>3650</sup>**. There are **10<sup>82</sup>** atoms in the universe.

Comment: But what about    
T(n)= n^2.001 + n^2logn

Comment: Your plot is misleading. Any power of `n` dominates `log(n)`. With such a slowly growing function as `n^0.001`, it's going to take an enormous value for `n` before the lines cross, though.

Comment: @axiom I eliminated the common factor of `n^2` from each.

Comment: Incidentally, I tried plotting out the curves on *logarithmic* axes, and they still haven't crossed when I  reach the limit of the largest floats my graphing program can handle. So any number representable as a double is still in the "small enough that constant factors matter" regime; that includes such piddling small numbers as the number of possible chess board configurations or the number of atoms in the observable universe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90952/discussion-between-axiom-and-michael-j-barber).

Answer (score 1):

> `T(n)=n^2 + n^2logn`
>
> What is the big Oh and omega of this function? Also, what's little oh?

Quoting a previous answer:

> Don't forget big O notation represents a set. `O(g(n))` is the set of
>   of all function `f` such that `f` does not grows faster than `g`,
>   formally is the same is saying that there exists `C` and `n0` such
>   that we have `|f(n)| <= C|g(n)|` for every `n >= n0`. The expression
>   `f(n) = O(g(n))` is a shorthand for saying that `f(n)` is in the set
>   `O(g(n))`

Also you can think of big O as `≤` and of small o as `<` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation/1364582)). So you care of more of finding relevant big O  bound than small o.  In your case it's even appropriate to use big theta which is `=`. Since `n^2 log n` dominates `n^2` it's true that

```
T1(n)=n^2 + n^2logn = Ө(n^2 logn)
```

Now the second part. `log n` grows so slowly that even `n^e, e > 0` dominates it. Interestingly, you can even prove that `lim n^e/(logn)^k=inf` as n goes to infinity. From this you have that `n^0.001` dominates `log n` then

```
T2(n)=n^2.001 + n^2logn = Ө(n^2.001).
```

If `f(n) = Ө(g(n))` it's also true that `f(n) = O(g(n))` so to answer your question:

- `T1(n)=O(n^2 logn)`
- `T2(n)=O(n^2.001)`