# Lower bounds for logarithmic functions

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I asked a similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845274/asymptotic-complexity-of-logarithmic-functions) 
I want to ask a follow up question on lower bounds or omega. For the following recurrence,

> T<sub>2</sub>(n)=n<sup>2.001</sup> + n<sup>2</sup>logn

T<sub>2</sub>(n)=O(n<sup>2.001</sup>). I have no problems with that. But I was also told that for lower bounds, T<sub>2</sub>(n)=Ω(n<sup>2.001</sup>) even though n<sup>2</sup>logn is supposed to be smaller than n<sup>2.0001</sup>. Help?

Comment: Are we supposed to read `n^2logn` as `(n^2) log n` or as `n ^ (2 log n)`?

Comment: Yesterday I told you that `T2(n)=n^2.001 + n^2logn = Ө(n^2.001)`.  Since `Ө = O  ∩ Omega` you can say  `T2(n) = Omegan^2.001()`

Comment: But why is T2(n)=omega(n^2.001) if (n^2.001)>(n^2 logn) at some large n...
Wouldn't there be some k such that T(k) has complexity that is sandwiched between f(k)=k^2.001 and g(k)=(k^2 logk)?

Comment: Why would the lower bound on n^2 * log(n)...?

Comment: @JosephD `T2(n)=Omega(n^2.001)` (big omega) and `T2(n)=omega(n^2)`. There is a big difference between small o and big O. `omega = '>'` and `Omega = '>='`. So your question is analogous to asking give me a lower of bound of `5`. People tell you that `5 >= 3` but a better lower bound for `5` is `5` itself since `5>=5`. Do you get it now?

Answer (score 1):

Big Omega is used as a lower bound, so `T2(n)=Ω(n^2 * logn)` is perfectly valid.  However, `T2(n)=Ω(n^2.001)` offers a tighter lower bound.