# Confused on Little O meaning

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, computer-science, little-o

So what I took from [little o page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation) is when you apply the small O notation we have to check if one rate is faster then the other (small o focuses on the upper bound)?

In this case when we apply small o:

2^n = o(3^n) will be false as 2^n and 3^n upper bound is equal in speed but not less then

2n = o(n^2) is true as n^2 upper bound is 2 and 2n does not have an upper bound.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if you ask this on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @KurtRevis I am more focused on algorithm and programming. This could also be in cs but could also be in stack over flow. I am just trying to be better at programming and computational. Sadly, I am not studying or learning computer science (I am self learning), I have just googled "effective programming" and came across this, which is a small part to cs and the whole of the programming industry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2^n` is in `o(3^n)` (little o), since:

```
lim_n->infinity (2^n / 3^n) = 0
```

Simmilarly. for `2n`, it is easy to show that it is in `o(n^2)`

An intuitive for "little o" is - it's an upper bound, but not a tight one. It means, a function `f(n)` is in `o(g(n))` if f(n) is in `O(g(n))`, but not in `Omega(g(n))`.

In your example, `2^n` is in `O(3^n)`, but it is not in `Omega(3^n)`, so we can say it is in `o(3^n)`

Comment: I kind of understood that. Are trying to say 2^n = o(3^n) is true? Because In the link that is provided it has to be less then with small o and with big O it could be less then or equal to... Im just confused sorry.

Comment: @SA since `lim_{n->infinity} (2^n/3^n) = 0`, `2^n` is  NOT in `Omega(3^n)`. and since it is also in `O(3^n)`, we can conclude it is in `o(2^n)`.

Answer (score 1):

the only difference between the big O and Small O is that big O allows the function to grow at equal phase however the small O states that g(x) has higher rate of growth and can never be equal after a specific point x'(considering f(x)=o(g(x)) )

The first example you have provided is wrong as small O  states that:
for f(x)=o(g(x))
|f(x)|x'

however in the above case where f(x)=2^x and g(x)=3^x there exists no C and x' to satisfy it
as g(x) has higher rate of growth.

the best way to define small O if you understand Big O is:

A function is called small O if it is Big O but not Big Omega 
-- this is because the big omega and big O only intersect at the condition when the rate of groth of both function s is equal so if we remove that specific case it is small O.

However please remember that if f(x) is Big O g(x) it can also be small O of g(x) however vice versa is not possible.