# When does one typically prefer the little-o instead of the big-O?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, little-o

I understand the difference between the Big-O and the little-o, however I wonder when/why one would choose the little-o over the big-O for a particular situation (and the opposite).

Comment: Choose? There is nothing about choice there...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Big-O and Little-O Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation)

Answer (score 1):

You can chose to describe an algorithm or requirement using little-o notation when you want to emphasize the difference from big O, or if you want to ensure "something is better than..."

A naive example - if you need a 3rd party to create some library for you, and you want to ensure the query time is sublinear, the mathematical notation for sublinear will be `o(n)`, where `o(.)` is the little o notation.