# Asymptotic analysis "o" to "O" conversion

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

My understanding about "O" and "o" notation is that former is an upper bound and latter is a tight bound. My question is, if a function., f(n) is tight bound by some random function., say o(g(n)). Can this bound be made an upper bound i.e.,(O(g(n))  by multiplying some constant "c" such that it will be an upper bound even when n->infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f ∈ O(g) says, essentially

> For at least one choice of a constant k > 0, you can find a constant a
>   such that the inequality 0 <= f(x) <= k g(x) holds for all x > a.

Note that O(g) is the set of all functions for which this condition holds.

f ∈ o(g) says, essentially

> For every choice of a constant k > 0, you can find a constant a such
>   that the inequality 0 <= f(x) < k g(x) holds for all x > a.

Once again, note that o(g) is a set.

From Wikipedia:

> Note the difference between the earlier formal definition for the
>   big-O notation, and the present definition of little-o: while the
>   former has to be true for at least one constant M the latter must hold
>   for every positive constant ε, however small. In this way, little-o
>   notation makes a stronger statement than the corresponding big-O
>   notation: **every function that is little-o of g is also big-O of g, but
>   not every function that is big-O of g is also little-o of g** (for
>   instance g itself is not, unless it is identically zero near ∞).

This link contains good explanation:
http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/13/lectures/app-b.pdf

Comment: o(g) is a set of what. Can you give an example. Thanks in advance

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation this might help

Comment: I have read those docs. So that means f(n) can be either O(g(n)) or o(g(n)). It can't have both relations w.r.t g(n) Because I have seen few examples that has both "o" and "O"  relation with g(n)!! Confusing. How can it have both "o" and "O"

Comment: You can accept answers with current reputation also. Are you able to see green correct mark in my answer just below up-vote button on top left ? try that. are you getting any error when you click on that?