# Big O Notation example claiming 2n^2 = O(n^3)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

While I was studying time complexity, I found a web page explaining about Big O notation.

While I was reading I found the example they used and it got me confused.

In the example they said something like

`2n^{2} = O(n^{3})` because for all n bigger than `2(n_{0})`, there exists a c(which is 1) that satisfies `0 <= 2n^{2} <= cn^{3}`

First I thought the Big O should be `O(n^2)`. But after reading through few more texts I can see that `n^2` is smaller than `n^3` so can theoretically say that the big O is `O(n^3)`.
But is `O(n^2)` wrong for the example above?

Comment: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely correct (though you should write out the proof for O(n^2) to convince yourself). Technically the example as written is not wrong, but it's also not a good example. You can think of O(g) as meaning that the function grows as slowly or slower than g. So if a function is O(n^2) it is also O(n^3). There are other variations on Big-O notation (Theta and Omega) which make stronger statements about the asymptotic behavior.

This thread had some nice information even though the focus of the question is slightly different [Difference between Big-O and Little-O Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation).