# What is a loose bound in asymptotic notation?

Tags: math, time-complexity, complexity-theory

When describing a loose bound, can I pick any value for the proper notation that is not close at all to the actual value for the asymptotic notation? If my function is n^2 + n, could I say a loose upper bound is O(n^3), and could I say that a loose lower bound is Ω(1)? Would such statements be valid? When do I know that my loose bound is valid or not?

Answer (score 1):

From the here [Difference between Big-O and Little-O Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation) talking about Big-O vs little-o, it would be fine to say your `n^2+n` is `O(n^3)` and this is a loose upper bound. However most people would describe it as `O(n^2)` as this is more accurate and tells you that the algorithm is actually faster than `O(n^3)`

I think "loose bound" might come up more when something isn't completely known. For instance the naive recursive Fibonacci function:

```py
def fibo(n):
  if n == 1 or n == 2:
    return 1
  return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
```

You could say that this is `O(2^n)` because the function makes 2 recursive calls so it's doubling at each step. However, one side of this "tree" (if you were to expand out the function calls it looks sort of like a tree) will bottom out to a base case faster than the other because it's `n-1` vs `n-2`. This means the "tree" is lopsided and so it will actually be faster than `O(2^n)`. Hence `O(2^n)` is a "loose upper bound."

Finding a tighter bound is left as an exercise to the reader ;)