# What exactly does big Ө notation represent?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, notation, big-o

I'm really confused about the differences between big O, big Omega, and big Theta notation.

I understand that big O is the upper bound and big Omega is the lower bound, but what exactly does big Ө (theta) represent?

I have read that it means ***tight bound***, but what does that mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between lower bound and tight bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464078/difference-between-lower-bound-and-tight-bound)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

It means that the algorithm is both big-O and big-Omega in the given function.

For example, if it is `Ө(n)`, then there is some constant `k`, such that your function (run-time, whatever), is larger than `n*k` for sufficiently large `n`, and some other constant `K` such that your function is smaller than `n*K` for sufficiently large `n`.

In other words, for sufficiently large `n`, it is sandwiched between two linear functions :

For `k < K` and `n` sufficiently large, `n*k < f(n) < n*K`

Comment: It does not, those variables are a bit confusing, they are unrelated.

Comment: @committedandroider No, they are lowercase and uppercase thus different, he's using typical mathematical style in which two "similar" (but not related in any way here) variables use big and small case.

Answer (score 382):

First let's understand what big O, big Theta and big Omega are. They are all [sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) of functions.

Big O is giving upper [asymptotic bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote), while big Omega is giving a lower bound. Big Theta gives both.

Everything that is `Ө(f(n))` is also `O(f(n))`, but not the other way around.

`T(n)` is said to be in `Ө(f(n))` if it is both in `O(f(n))` and in `Omega(f(n))`. 
In sets terminology, **`Ө(f(n))` is the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Intersections) of `O(f(n))` and `Omega(f(n))`**

For example, merge sort worst case is both `O(n*log(n))` and `Omega(n*log(n))` - and thus is also `Ө(n*log(n))`, but it is also `O(n^2)`, since `n^2` is asymptotically "bigger" than it. However, it is **not** `Ө(n^2)`, Since the algorithm is not `Omega(n^2)`.

#### A bit deeper mathematic explanation

`O(n)` is asymptotic upper bound. If `T(n)` is `O(f(n))`, it means that from a certain `n0`, there is a constant `C` such that `T(n) <= C * f(n)`. On the other hand,  big-Omega says there is a constant `C2` such that `T(n) >= C2 * f(n))`).

#### Do not confuse!

Not to be confused with worst, best and average cases analysis: all three (Omega, O, Theta) notation are **not** related to the best, worst and average cases analysis of algorithms. Each one of these can be applied to each analysis.

**We usually use it to analyze complexity of algorithms** (like the merge sort example above). When we say "Algorithm A is `O(f(n))`", what we really mean is "The algorithms complexity under the worst<sup>1</sup> case analysis is `O(f(n))`" - meaning - it scales "similar" (or formally, not worse than) the function `f(n)`.

#### Why we care for the asymptotic bound of an algorithm?

Well, there are many reasons for it, but I believe the most important of them are:

1. It is much harder to determine the *exact* complexity function, thus we "compromise" on the big-O/big-Theta notations, which are informative enough theoretically.
2. The exact number of ops is also *platform dependent*. For example, if we have a vector (list) of 16 numbers. How much ops will it take? The answer is: it depends. Some CPUs allow vector additions, while other don't, so the answer varies between different implementations and different machines, which is an undesired property. The big-O notation however is much more constant between machines and implementations.

To demonstrate this issue, have a look at the following graphs:
[image]

It is clear that `f(n) = 2*n` is "worse" than `f(n) = n`. But the difference is not quite as drastic as it is from the other function. We can see that `f(n)=logn` quickly getting much lower than the other functions, and `f(n) = n^2` is quickly getting much higher than the others.

So - because of the reasons above, we "ignore" the constant factors (2* in the graphs example), and take only the big-O notation.

In the above example, `f(n)=n, f(n)=2*n` will both be in `O(n)` and in `Omega(n)` - and thus will also be in `Theta(n)`.

On the other hand - `f(n)=logn` will be in `O(n)` (it is "better" than `f(n)=n`), but will NOT be in `Omega(n)` - and thus will also NOT be in `Theta(n)`.

Symmetrically, `f(n)=n^2` will be in `Omega(n)`, but NOT in `O(n)`, and thus - is also NOT `Theta(n)`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Usually, though not always. when the analysis class (worst, average and best) is missing, we really mean **the worst case.**

Comment: +1 for the nice explanation, I have a confusion ,you have written in last line that ,, f(n)=n^2 will be in Omega(n). but not in O(n) .and thus is also not Theta(n) >how?

Comment: @krishnaChandra: `f(n) = n^2` is asymptotically stronger then `n`, and thus is Omega(n). However it is not O(n) (because for large `n` values, it is bigger then `c*n`, for all `n`). Since we said Theta(n) is the intersection of O(n) and Omega(n), since it is not O(n), it cannot be Theta(n) as well.

Comment: It's great to see someone explain how big-O notation isn't related to the best/worst case running time of an algorithm. There are so many websites that come up when I google the topic that say O(T(n)) means the worse case running time.

Comment: @almel It's 2*n (2n, two times n) not 2^n

Comment: really usefull explanations to explain theta in a simple way

Comment: "O(n) is asymptotic lower bound" - did you mean Omega? O(n) is the upper bound.

Comment: @whonoes thank you, seems like it got confused during edits or something (or maybe I just mispelled from the first place). fixed that. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: for n^2, you can use the tag `<sup>2</sup>`. Anyway, wonderful answer.

Comment: @Xenomorph That was supposed to be "worse". thanks. Fixed, along with some typos.

Comment: A beautiful explanation! Can we say that  **1.** `O(f(n))` represents the behavior of an algorithm when `n` (the number of input elements) `tends to infinity`.  ** 2.**  `Omega(f(n))` represents the behavior of an algorithm when `n tends to zero`.  **3.**  `Theta(f(n))` represents the actual behavior of the algorithm for `0 < n < infinity` ?  *Please correct me if I am wrong.*

Comment: @VishalK 1. Big O is the **upper** bound as _n_ tends to infinity. 2. Omega is the **lower** bound as _n_ tends to infinity. 3. Theta is both the **upper and lower** bound as _n_ tends to infinity. Note that all bounds are only valid "as _n_ tends to infinity", because the bounds do not hold for low values of _n_ (less than _n0_). The bounds hold for all _n_ ≥ _n0_, but not below _n0_ where lower order terms become dominant.

Comment: @bain : Thank you so much for clarifying my doubts.

Comment: I still don't understand how O and Omega are not worst and best case. Could you provide an example with best, worst and average cases of an algorithm and provide their corresponding O, Theta and Omega?

Comment: Is O just about being not slower? And Omega just about being not faster? So, in the worst case, merge sort is not faster that nlogn and is not slower than nlogn? So, can we say that in the worst case it's exactly nlogn then? Or what does Theta mean in this case?

Comment: What is an example of an algorithm whose Theta is different from its O? Does this kind of algorithm even exist?

Comment: @hey_you Read the answer again. big O,Theta,Omega are for functions, not algorithms. Merge sort is Omega(n) worst case. It is also O(n^2) best case. It is also Theta (nlogn) worst case. Basically, for each analysis (worst/best/average/...) you have a complexity function `T_best(n), T_worst(n), T_average(n)`. They do not have to be identical (and mostly, they are not). O/Omega/Theta can be applied to any of them independently.

Comment: @amit, so, O(n log n) - not faster than n log n, Omega(n log n) - not slower than n log n, Theta(n log n) - exactly n log n? Is that the meaning behind these functions?

Comment: @hey_you, as amit said in his answer that "O(n) is asymptotic upper bound. If T(n) is O(f(n)), it means that from a certain n0, there is a constant C such that T(n) **<=** C * f(n). On the other hand, big-Omega says there is a constant C2 such that T(n) **>=** C2 * f(n))).", so you are right.  
Please note that in case of small-o and small-omega functions, your statement isn't true. For more reading about the specified functions, please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation)

Comment: Finally an understandable answer.

Answer (score 16):

**Theta(n):** A function `f(n)` belongs to `Theta(g(n))`, if there exists positive constants `c1` and `c2` such that `f(n)` can be sandwiched between `c1(g(n))` and `c2(g(n))`. i.e it gives both upper and as well as lower bound.

> *Theta(g(n)) = { f(n) : there exists positive constants c1,c2 and n1 such that 
>                   0<=c1(g(n))<=f(n)<=c2(g(n)) for all n>=n1 }*

when we say `f(n)=c2(g(n))` or `f(n)=c1(g(n))` it represents asymptotically tight bound.

**O(n):** It gives only upper bound (may or may not be tight)

> *O(g(n)) = { f(n) : there exists positive constants c and n1 such that 0<=f(n)<=cg(n) for all n>=n1}*

*ex*: The bound `2*(n^2) = O(n^2)` is asymptotically tight, whereas the bound `2*n = O(n^2)` is not asymptotically tight.

**o(n):** It gives only upper bound (never a tight bound)

> the notable difference between O(n) & o(n) is f(n) is less than cg(n)
>   for all n>=n1 but not equal as in O(n).

*ex*: `2*n = o(n^2)`, but `2*(n^2) != o(n^2)`

Comment: You didn't mention big Omega, which refers to the lower-bound.  Otherwise, very nice first answer and welcome!

Comment: i liked the way he framed the definition of Theta(n). Upvoted!

Comment: Is it right to think of theta as the 'average' time for a function? I keep hearing people refer to it as the average but I am not sure if the fact it is simply constrained by an upper and lower boundary really means its an average.

Answer (score 7):

I hope this is what you may want to find in the classical [CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)(page 66): 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Big Theta notation:

Nothing to mess up buddy!!

If we have a positive valued functions f(n) and g(n) takes a positive valued argument n then ϴ(g(n)) defined as {f(n):there exist constants c1,c2 and n1 for all n>=n1}

where c1 g(n)<=f(n)<=c2 g(n)

### Let's take an example:

let f(n)=5n^2+2n+1

g(n)=n^2

c1=5 and c2=8 and n1=1

Among all the notations ,ϴ notation gives the best intuition about the rate of growth of function because it gives us a tight bound unlike  big-oh and big -omega
which gives the upper and lower bounds respectively.

ϴ tells us that g(n) is as close as f(n),rate of growth of g(n) is as close to the rate of growth of f(n) as possible.

[image: see the image to get a better intuition]

Answer (score 2):

**First of all, theory**

1. Big O = upper limit O(n)
2. Theta = Order function - theta(n)
3. Omega = Q-Notation (lower limit) Q(n)

### Why are people so confused?

In many blogs and books, these statements are emphasised, like:

"This is Big O(n^3)", etc.

And people often confuse like whether

O(n) == theta(n) == Q(n)

But what is worth keeping in mind is they are just ***mathematical functions*** with names O, Theta, and Omega.

So they have the same general formula of a polynomial.

Let,

f(n) = 2n4 + 100n2 + 10n + 50 then,

g(n) = n4, So g(n) is the function which takes a function as input and returns variable with the biggest power,

> The same f(n) & g(n) for all the explanations below:

### Big O(n) - provides an upper bound

Big O(n4) = 3n4, because 3n4 > 2n4

**3n4 is the value of Big O(n4), just like f(x) = 3x**

**n4** is playing a role of **x** here so,

Replacing n4 with x'so, Big O(x') = 2x'. Now we both are happy with what the general concept is.

So 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ **O(x')**

**O(x') = cg(n) = 3n4**

Putting value,

0 ≤ 2n4 + 100n2 + 10n + 50 ≤ 3n4

**3n4 is our upper bound**

### Big Omega(n) - provides a lower bound

Theta(n4) = cg(n) = 2n4, because 2n4 ≤ our example f(n)

**2n4 is the value of Theta(n4)**

so, 0 ≤ cg(n) ≤ f(n)

0 ≤ 2n4 ≤ 2n4 + 100n2 + 10n + 50

**2n4 is our lower bound**

### Theta(n) - provides a tight bound

This is calculated to find out that weather the lower bound is similar to the upper bound.

Case 1). The upper bound is similar to the lower bound

```
if the upper bound is similar to the lower bound, the average case is similar

Example, 2n4 ≤ f(x) ≤ 2n4,
Then Theta(n) = 2n4
```

Case 2). If the upper bound is not similar to the lower bound

```
In this case, Theta(n) is not fixed, but Theta(n) is the set of functions with the same order of growth as g(n).

Example 2n4 ≤ f(x) ≤ 3n4, this is our default case.
Then, Theta(n) = c'n4, is a set of functions with 2 ≤ c' ≤ 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why there isn't any short simple answer explaining big theta in plain English (seems like that was the question), so here it is.

Big Theta is the range of values or the exact value (if big O and big Omega are equal) within which the operations needed for a function will grow.