# How to add Big O and Big omega

Tags: algorithm, analysis, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

If an algorithm has two sub algorithm, when it is best case for sub algorithm A1 to the given input, it is the worst case for sub algorithm A2. How could I find the overall algorithm complexity?
Simply I mean Ω(N) + O(N)=?
I know if the algorithms are in sequential executing order the over all complexity is O(N)+ O(N) and in nested order O(N)* O(N).

Please tell me in both cases, when in sequential and in nested order

Comment: It is hard to tell what is your question.

Comment: Best case and worst case are different then big O and big Omega. Best case/Worst case/avg case are analysis of algorithms. The analysis results in a function. big O and big Omega are sets of functions. Each one of big O/big Omega/big Theta can be applied to each of best/worst/avg case analysis. I tried to explain this issue among others answering [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/big-theta-notation/12338937#12338937)

Comment: Simple, how to add runtime complexities of two algorithms? When one's complexity is big O and other's is big omega? Ω() + O()=?

Answer (score 6):

Essentially Ω(N) + O(N)= Ω(N). Because O(N) means lower (or at most the same) order of Ω(N). When they are summed, the lower order can be omitted.

Comment: What is the + operator for *sets*? Omega and O are both sets of function, what is `SET + SET`? I am not familiar with a standard definition for it:|

Comment: It's a slight abuse of notation. Ω(N) + O(N) = Ω(N) means if function f in Ω(N), and g in O(N), then f+g in Ω(N).

Answer (score 4):

If your algorithm includes one operation which takes (for example) O(N) time, and another which takes O(N^2) time, then the overall complexity is O(N^2). There's no such thing as O(N^2 + N). The same goes for Ω(). This answers your question about "sequential executing order".

If your algorithm includes N operations, each of which takes O(N) time, then the overall complexity is O(N^2). The same goes for Ω(). You just multiply the polynomials, and take the term which grows most quickly with increasing N. This answers your question about "nested execution order".

Comment: If better-educated readers find anything incorrect in this post, please correct me!

Comment: O(N^2+N) exists as a set but O(N^2+N)=O(N)