# Which is better: O(n log n) or O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Okay so I have this project I have to do, but I just don't understand it. The thing is, I have 2 algorithms. **O(n^2)** and **O(n*log<sub>2</sub>n)**.

Anyway, I find out in the project info that if **n<100**, then **O(n^2)** is more efficient, but if **n>=100**, then **O(n*log<sub>2</sub>n)** is more efficient. I'm suppose to demonstrate with an example using numbers and words or drawing a photo. But the thing is, I don't understand this and I don't know how to demonstrate this.

Anyone here that can help me understand how this works?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just ask [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20n%20log%28n%29%20/%20n%5E2) if you have doubts.

In this case, it says

```
     n log(n)
lim --------- = 0
       n^2
```

Or you can also calculate the limit yourself:

```
     n log(n)        log(n)   (Hôpital)       1/n          1
lim --------- = lim --------      =     lim ------- = lim --- = 0
       n^2             n                       1           n
```

That means `n^2` grows faster, so `n log(n)` is smaller (better), when `n` is high enough.

Answer (score 116):

Good question. Actually, I always show these 3 pictures:

[n = [0; 10]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20n%5E2%20and%20n*log%20n%20and%20n%20where%20n%20from%200%20to%2010)

[image]

[n = [0; 100]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20n%5E2%20and%20n*log%20n%20and%20n%20where%20n%20from%200%20to%20100)

[image]

[n = [0; 1000]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20n%5E2%20and%20n*log%20n%20and%20n%20where%20n%20from%200%20to%201000)

[image]

So, `O(N*log(N))` is far better than `O(N^2)`. It is much closer to `O(N)` than to `O(N^2)`.

But your `O(N^2)` algorithm is faster for `N < 100` in real life. There are a lot of reasons why it can be faster. Maybe due to better memory allocation or other "non-algorithmic" effects. Maybe `O(N*log(N))` algorithm requires some data preparation phase or `O(N^2)` iterations are shorter. Anyway, Big-O notation is only appropriate in case of large enough Ns.

If you want to demonstrate why one algorithm is faster for small Ns, you can measure *execution time of 1 iteration* and *constant overhead* for both algorithms, then use them to correct theoretical plot:

[Example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%200.33%20*%20n%5E2%20and%201000%20%2b%205*%20n*log%20n%20where%20n%20from%200%20to%20200)

[image]

Or just measure execution time of both algorithms for different `Ns` and plot empirical data.

Comment: a Much needed explanation. thx for the images and comparison.

Answer (score 19):

Big-O notation is a notation of [asymptotic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_computational_complexity). This means it calculates the complexity when N is arbitrarily large.

For small Ns, a lot of other factors come in. It's possible that an algorithm has O(n^2) loop iterations, but each iteration is very short, while another algorithm has O(n) iterations with very long iterations. With large Ns, the linear algorithm will be faster. With small Ns, the quadratic algorithm will be faster.

So, for small Ns, just measure the two and see which one is faster. No need to go into asymptotic complexity.

Incidentally, don't write the basis of the log. Big-O notation ignores constants - O(17 * N) is the same as O(N). Since log<sub>2</sub>N is just `ln N / ln 2`, the basis of the logarithm is just another constant and is ignored.

Answer (score 14):

Let's compare them,

On one hand we have:

```
n^2 = n * n
```

On the other hand we have:

```
nlogn = n * log(n)
```

Putting them side to side:

```
n * n    versus    n * log(n)
```

Let's divide by `n` which is a common term, to get:

```
n    versus    log(n)
```

Let's compare values:

```
n = 10           log(n) ~ 2.3
n = 100          log(n) ~ 4.6
n = 1,000        log(n) ~ 6.9
n = 10,000       log(n) ~ 9.21
n = 100,000      log(n) ~ 11.5
n = 1,000,000    log(n) ~ 13.8
```

So we have:

```
n >> log(n) for n > 1

n^2 >> n log(n) for n > 1
```

Comment: @ Khaled ,what is  the value of base ,i thought of 2 and it is giving me val of log 10 (base 2) as 3.32 ,can you confirm me once?

Comment: @N.Nihar I used Wolfram Alpha and it assumed Natural Log (which is base `e ~ 2.7`), if you work on Binary Trees you can use base `2`, if you take base `10`, you would have `10^n`, and the `log10` would be the number of digits after the left-most `1`: `1000 = 10^3 = 10*10*10, log10(1000) = log10(10^3) = 3`

Answer (score 3):

> Anyway, I find out in the project info that if n<100, then O(n^2) is
> more efficient, but if n>=100, then O(n*log2n) is more efficient.

Let us start by clarifying what is `Big O` notation in the current context. From ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)) one can read:

> **Big O notation is a mathematical notation** that describes the limiting
> behavior of a function when the argument tends **towards a particular
> value or infinity**. (..) **In computer science,** big O notation is used to classify algorithms
> according to how their run time or space requirements grow **as the
> input size grows**.

`Big O` notation does not represent a function but rather a [set of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%D3%A8-notation-represent) with a certain asymptotic upper-bound; as one can read from [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):

> Big O notation characterizes functions according to their growth
> rates: different functions with the same growth rate may be
> represented using the same `O` notation.

Informally, in computer-science [time-complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) and [space-complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) theories, one can think of the `Big O` notation as a categorization of algorithms with a certain worst-case scenario concerning time and space, respectively. For instance, `O(n)`:

> An algorithm is said to take linear time/space, or O(n) time/space, if its time/space complexity is O(n). Informally, this means that the running time/space increases at most linearly with the size of the input ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time)).

and `O(n log n)` as:

> An algorithm is said to run in quasilinear time/space if T(n) = O(n log^k n) for some positive constant k; linearithmic time/space is the case k = 1 ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linearithmic_time)).

Mathematically speaking the statement

> Which is better: O(n log n) or O(n^2)

is not accurate, since as mentioned before `Big O` notation represents a [set of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%D3%A8-notation-represent). Hence, more accurate would have been "does `O(n log n)` contains `O(n^2)`". Nonetheless, typically such relaxed phrasing is normally used to quantify (for the worst-case scenario) how a set of algorithms behaves compared with another set of algorithms regarding the increase of their input sizes. To compare two classes of algorithms (*e.g.*, `O(n log n)` and  `O(n^2)`) instead of

> Anyway, I find out in the project info that if n<100, then O(n^2) is
> more efficient, but if n>=100, then O(n*log2n) is more efficient.

you should analyze how both classes of algorithms behaves with the increase of their input size (*i.e.,* n) for the worse-case scenario; analyzing `n` when it tends to the infinity

[image]

As @[cem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14773728/cem) rightly point it out, in the image "`big-O` denote one of the asymptotically least upper-bounds of the plotted functions, and does not refer to the sets `O(f(n))`"

As you can see in the image after a certain input, `O(n log n)` (green line) grows slower than `O(n^2)` (orange line). That is why (for the worst-case) `O(n log n)` is more desirable than `O(n^2)` because one can increase the input size, and the growth rate will increase slower with the former than with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not quite correct to compare asymptotic complexity mixed with N constraint. I.E., I can state:

- `O(n^2)` is slower than `O(n * log(n))`, because the definition of [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) will include `n is growing infinitely`.
- For particular `N` it is possible to say which algorithm is faster by simply comparing `N^2 * ALGORITHM_CONSTANT` and `N * log(N) * ALGORITHM_CONSTANT`, where `ALGORITHM_CONSTANT` depends on the algorithm. For example, if we traverse array twice to do our job, asymptotic complexity will be `O(N)` and `ALGORITHM_CONSTANT` will be `2`.

Also I'd like to mention that `O(N * log2N)` which I assume logariphm on basis `2` (log<sub>2</sub>N) is actually the same as `O(N * log(N))` because of logariphm properties.

Answer (score 0):

*We have two way to compare two Algo*
->first way is very simple compare and apply limit

```
T1(n)-Algo1

T2(n)=Alog2

  lim  (n->infinite) T1(n)/T2(n)=m
```

(i)if m=0 Algo1 is faster than Algo2

(ii)m=k  Both are same

(iii)m=infinite  Algo2 is faster

*Second way pretty simple as compare to 1st there you just take a log of both but do not neglet multi constant

```
             Algo 1=log n

             Algo 2=sqr(n)

             keep log n =x

             Any poly>its log


   O(sqr(n))>o(logn)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a mathematician so i will try to explain why n^2 is faster than nlogn for small values of n , with a simple limit , while n-->0 :

lim n^2 / nlogn = lim n / logn = 0 / -inf = 0

so , for small values of n ( in this case "small value" is n existing in [1,99] ) , the nlogn is faster than n^2 , 'cause as we see limit = 0 .
But why n-->0? Because n in an algorithm can take "big" values , so when n<100 , it is considered like a very small value so we can take the limit n-->0.

Comment: Did you mean in your first sentence "why n^2 is faster than nlogn for small values of n?" There are situations (especially when using specific sorting methods) that a sort that is usually horrible with large N due to being N^2 for worst case but that sorting method is actually preferred for values of N under a specific number. As a very simplistic example, a function that is N^2 worst case may run 100x faster than a function with nlogn when N=1, so N can go up to a certain value before nlogn becomes the preferred method.

Comment: Yeah , thanks for the correction . I try to figure out why that happens , mathematically , but finding algorithms like that you mention  , is a better way to prove it .