# Understanding asymptotic notations with less mathematical background

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity

Okay! I am a complete newbie to the field of algorithms.

I could form a equation (e.g., `2n^2+3n+2`) from the algorithm and what I know is, only the highest power of the relation is considered for the order of growth of algorithms (such as `O(n^2)`), and I couldn't go beyond that.

I referred a lot of books but due to my lesser knowledge in math, still helpless. I could see a lot of `f(n)`, `O(g(n))` kinda things and what I understood from them is that ignoring the constants (since they are negligible for larger input sets)

`f(n)` lies between 0 and the upper bound `constant*(g(n))` but I couldn't find what the books/standard university video tutorials mean by their relations `g(n)`.

The asymptotic notations sound mathematically rigorous to me. Can someone help/link me to the correct place to learn these notations (0,theta, and omege) with lesser knowledge in math?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations It´s not that hard

Comment: Note that in the linked thread - most answers discuss big Theta, and not big O.

Comment: The thread [Big Theta Notation - what exactly does big Theta represent?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10376740/572670) discusses about the differences between the different notations.