# Time complexity: big-O, omega, teta. What are them?

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

I just read here [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm) about Time Complexity of an algorithm.

I will take the college admissions exam and I need to know what is Time Complexity and how to count/tell the time complexity of an algorithm.

I read above about `O()` and I think I understand, but I need to know about: `Ω()`,`o()`,`Θ()`.

Can anyone explain me clearly about this? Please note that I just finished highschool.

Thank you all!

Comment: I think it is not a duplicate of what big teta means. I said about omega too. I think also, it is not a duplicate while http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%d3%a8-notation-represent didn't solved my problem.

Comment: I think the duplicate link provides all the answers you need, if it doesn't, please take a look at the wikipedia page on big O notation (pretty good page, especially the summary table) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation. If you still have troubles understanding these notations, please edit (or repost) your question with details on what you did not understand because with the available information from your post, no more explanation than the duplicate link can be given.