# Confusion between worst case running time and Omega Notation

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I was asked this question:

Which of these sorting algorithms have a worst-case running time of Ω(n2) — Bubble Sort, Heap Sort, Insertion Sort, Merge Sort, Quick Sort (with good median finding), Selection Sort.

Can someone explain what needs to be done?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? What the omega notation means? How the algorithms work? How to calculate their time complexity?

Comment: What is meant by worst case running time of Omega n^2

Comment: Worst case is denoted by BigOh right? So why Omega is used?

Comment: You're confusing 2 different things. Worst-case running time of an algorithm means that the data is arranged in such a way that the algorithm takes the longest possible time for that data size. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_complexity) Wikipedia article. The big omega notation represents a relationship between data size and the time the algorithm takes. Answers to this question explain that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-%ce%98n-and-on

Comment: @vesan you mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/471470/2431281

Comment: @Keale Yes, that's a good short explanation. The top answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/471206/2428407) has a more technical one. Or, if you're feeling even more technical, there's always Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation

Comment: Then, the OP's question becomes confusing indeed. @JayPatel please add more details to your question. As it currently stands, it's hard to tell what you exactly want to know.

Comment: I also tried to explain that in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12338937/572670

Comment: This is the same as asking which of the algorithms have an input that proves the O(n^2) running time is tight.

Comment: @Keale I meant, what is to be done to reach the answer. Find Omega of all sorting algorithm and pick worst among all of them ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put it, the type of analysis and the notation are seperate terms. You can apply each of big-O,little-o,big-Omga,little-omega, big theta and more (like tilde notations) to any of the analysis (including: best case, worst case, average case).

You have the type of analysis. This gives you the complexity function, like for example for merge sort's worst case:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + CONST*n + SOME_CONSTANT
```

Then, you can analyse this `T(n)` and derive some conclusions. The asymptotic notations are set of functions, or "family" of functions that have common asymptotic behavior. For the above examples, you can conclude:

- This function is in Theta(nlogn)
- This function is in O(nlogn)
- This function is in Omega(1)
- This function is in O(n^3)