# Calculate Big-O Complexity

Tags: java, big-o, time-complexity

I will eventually be giving this program an input file of like 60,000 400-pixel images, so I am trying to get an idea of how this code will run with a large input. I replaced unimportant stuff with "blah" and all the ArrayList names with simple letters (`nn`, `mm`, and `kk`) for readability.

```
        for (Perceptron P : nn){
            //blah
        }
        for (Perceptron P : mm) {
            //blah
        }
        for (Perceptron P : kk){
            //blah
        }

        for (Perceptron P : mm) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nn; i++) {
                //blah
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < kk; j++){
                //blah
            }
        }

        for (Perceptron X : nn){
            for (Perceptron Y : mm){
                //blah
            }
        }

        for (Perceptron Z : kk){
            for (Perceptron Y : mm){
                //blah
            }
        }
```

I think the answer is O(`nn+mm+kk+mm(nn+kk)+nnmm+kkmm`). If I know that `nn` is 400, `mm` is 300, and `kk` is 10, then this is O(246710). But now I'm stuck. I don't really know what O(246710) means. Do I have to calculate the big-O with respect to only one of the variables at a time? If so, what good would that do? I'm just trying to get an idea of how this will perform. Thanks

Comment: You completely lack the understanding what Big-O is.  I suggest going through a tutorial.  Something like this: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html

Comment: `O(nn+mm+kk+mm(nn+kk)+nnmm+kkmm)` is `O(mmnn+mmkk+nnmm+kkmm)` which is `O(mmkk+nnmm)`. So, what this tells you is that `mm` is the most important factor - it multiples both arguments. `kk`and `nn` are less important, they multiply only their respective factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Big-O only concerns the biggest term in the running time, which is `O(mm*(nn+kk))` in this case.  The section of your code which generates this term is the following nested loop:

```
for (Perceptron P : mm) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nn; i++) {
        //blah
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < kk; j++){
        //blah
    }
}
```

If you reveal to us how `kk`, `mm`, and `nn` relate to the actual size of the image, then we can give you a bound on running time in more meaningful terms.

Answer (score 1):

O(N) means that the execution time of the program is linearly proportional to N. So, O(246710) does not really mean anything.

The complexity of your program is actually O(mm*(nn+kk)). That does not tell you anything about how long it will take on input of a particular size (for that, you would need to know how long all of the individual operations take), only that if, say, the size of `mm` doubles, while all other conditions are kept the same, then your program will take approximately twice as long to execute as before.

Answer (score 1):

Big O isn't exactly used the way you think it is. It is used to determine worst case scenario. Now if `nn`, `mm`, `kk` are all linear in data storage, and non-nested then it is simply `O('the-largest-chain')`. Now we do not know the relation between `nn`, `mm` and `kk`, so the best I can tell you is that; as you never nest them with themselves, it is linear.

Two quick examples to show it in action.

**Input:**

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3}
```

**Example #1**

```
for (int i : arr) {
    // do something
}
```

Big-O is in this case simply `O(n)`, as you only iterate from the start to finish of the array, it is directly proportional to the elements.

**Example #2**

```
for (int i : arr) {
    for (int j : arr) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now the relation between the input and the algorithm is quadratic, giving you `O(n2)`.

I recommend having a [read over here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), or follow a tutorial as it can clarify a lot more than my answer.

*In your case you are never nesting the input, and as no direct relation between the variables was given, then Big-O will simply be to add them up. Which should be `O(mm(nn+kk))` in your case.*

Answer (score 1):

With running time analysis of algorithms, you have [**Worst-Case**, **Average-Case**, and **Best-Case**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case) Scenarios, however the *order of the algorithm* is more important than the speed of the processor. This is relevant to the *number of operations* the algorithm takes to perform. ( also noted as **n** )

Here are a few examples using [Big-O-Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):

Linear: `60n + 5` or O(n). This means it takes n operations, your common loop

Quadratic: `2n^2 + 2n` or O(n^2). This is common in nested loops

Logarithmic: `number of digits in n` or O(1). This is used in Dictionaries, and will access an element after very few operations. ( Try and remember to apply this one for performance where applicable. )

Comment: Well no, with Big-O we have [worst case running time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12338937/2071828). Best case running time would be Big-omega.

Comment: Hi, I am curious why this [chart](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) still has these algorithms deduced by their best, worst, average cases, particularly on sorting. What is the difference in using big-O for time complexity analysis here vs Big-Omega? Perhaps there is an actual "Best Case" that is within the scope of Big-O? Are all best cases here really just Big-Omega? ( also have updated answer based on your comment )

Comment: @BoristheSpider Your link contradicts you. Big-O is an asymptotic upper bound, not the worst case running time. Read the 'Do not confuse!' section.

Answer (score 1):

Big-O notation represents the time in terms of input size, when size goes to infinity.

Firstly, you have to decide *input variable*. In your example, nn, mm and kk are input variables.

Then we calculate how many iteration we need to do:

```
nn + mm + kk + mm(nn + kk) + nn + kk
```

Simplifying:

```
2nn + 2kk + mm(nn + kk + 1)
```

We have 3 terms, but as all goes into infinity, only the term which has highest [asymptotic order of growth](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2014sp/recitations/20/review-of-asymptotic-complexity.html) will be significant, which is *mm(nn + kk + 1)*. You should really check asymptotic orders, because it would be too long to explain it in this answer.

We simplify *mm(nn + kk + 1)* to *mm(nn + kk)* because when it goes to infinity, a constant number doesn't matter(doesn't scale).

Now we have *mm(nn + kk)*, in here we select faster growing one among *nn* and *kk*, how to know which is faster growing? It depends on your input. Let's say we select nn, then we have *O(mm*nn)*. Which falls under **O(n^2)** category.

Answer (score 0):

The big O notation should be reduced to the biggest worst case denominator for the algortithm assuming all input sizes moves toward infinity.

So your expression O(nn+mm+kk+mm(nn+kk)+nnmm+kkmm) should be reduced to O(mmnn+mmkk).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right about the exact expression about the complexity  O(nn+mm+kk+mm(nn+kk)+nnmm+kkmm). it measures the complexity change with the variable , so don't replace the variable with value ,in your case when nn = 400, mm = 300 , kk = 10 it can be simplify to O(nn*mm) or O(nn*nn)