# How can merge sort have multiple big-oh values?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

In [What exactly does big Ө notation represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12338937), the most upvoted answer contains the following statement:

> For example, merge sort worst case is both `O(n*log(n))` and `Omega(n*log(n))` - and thus is also `Ө(n*log(n))`, but it is also `O(n^2)`, since `n^2` is asymptotically "bigger" than it. However, it is **not** `Ө(n^2)`, Since the algorithm is not `Omega(n^2)`.

I have two questions:

1. How do you determine that the worst case is `O(n*log(n))` and `Omega(n*log(n))`. In "Introduction to Algorithms" you determine the `Theta` time of insertion sort by counting number of times and cost of the execution of each statement. Is there a similar method for `O` and `Omega`?
2. How can merge sort's worst-case be `O(n*log(n))` but also `O(n^2)`?

Comment: Think of big O as "how clever you are" and big Omega as "the difficulty of the problem." It is much harder to prove big Omega than big O. In other words, you can solve a problem in O(N^2), but it could actually be a really easy problem with a linear solution.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you determine that the worst case is O(nLog(n)) and Ω(nLog(n)). In "Introduction to Algorithms" you determine the Theta time of insertion sort by counting number of times and cost of the execution of each statement. Is there a similar method for O and Omega?

- Merge Sort is a divide and conquer algorithm.
- You take a sequence of numbers, you break it in half recursively, you sort the halves individually and finally you merge the halves up recursively again leading to a sorted sequence of numbers.

Take the most simplistic case. How many elements do you touch<sup>*†*</sup> if you run the Merge Sort on that case? It is easy to visualize with the help of the image below. The elements touched at each level are *cn* and there are a total of *lg n* levels. So total elements touched, even in the easiest case, is *cnLog(n)*.

[image]

<sup>*[Image Source](https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-211f4ab8d850b1b8557832a61d98a2e1?convert_to_webp=true)*</sup>

Thus, *Merge Sort will **always** have a minimum complexity ≈ cnLog(n)* and that's also written as ***Merge Sort is Ω(nLog(n)).***

So even in the most simplistic run of this algorithm we have to touch the elements of the sequence a total of *cnLog(n)* times. Now...

**How many times do we touch the elements of the sequence otherwise?** Well, in any case whatsoever, the recursion tree of Merge Sort will be exactly the same as above. So, it turns out that we will always have a run-time complexity of Merge Sort proportional to *nLog(n)*! This means that both, the upper as well as the lower bound of Merge Sort is *cnLog(n)*.

Hence, ***Merge Sort's run time complexity is not only Ω(nLog(n)) but also O(nLog(n))*** which means that it is ***Ө(nLog(n)).***

<sub>You can see/visualize the calculations done for Merge Sort by the graphical explanation above, which shows the calculations done at each level of the tree.</sub>

---

> How can merge sort's worst-case be O(n*log(n)) but also O(n^2)?

That's straightforward, and I like the image below for understanding the terminologies.

[image]

<sup>*[Image Source](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/introduction-to-algorithms-13144/95/introduction-to-algorithms-39-728.jpg?cb=1227645582)*</sup>

Big-O only stresses on bounding above. It does not talk about **how far above**. So an algorithm can be described by more than one function as its Big-O complexity. However, the most informative of all of those is the one that is immediately above, otherwise every algorithm can simply be said to be O(*infinity*).

Now with that definition in place, we can easily say that Merge Sort is O(nLog(n)) as well as O(n<sup>2</sup>).

---

*<sup>†</sup><sub>'Touch' word in this explanation is the equivalent of what you have written in the question as "counting [the] number of times". During the run of the algorithm, every time a number is encountered - we say that the number is touched. So effectively we count the number of times a number is touched, to determine the complexity of the algorithm.</sub>*

Comment: I assume by simplest case you mean that the list is already sorted?

Comment: @Jon: Simplest case would be the one that finishes fastest. In case of Merge Sort all cases form the same size tree. That's how we get the running time in Theta as opposed to Big O or Omega.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to second question:**

When we say 'merge sort runs in `O(x)`' this is equivalent to saying 'merge sort has an asymptotic runtime behavior proportional to *at most* `x`'. In other words: `O(x)` stands for an upper bound. Note that this is independent of worst-case vs. best-case. You can give an upper bound for a best-case scenario, too.

To summarize: An algorithm can simultaneously have `O(n log n)`, `O(n^2)` etc, just as the number 3 is smaller than 5 and 10, simultaneously.

**Answer to first question:**

Most proofs for theta are actually composed of two separate proofs -- one for the lower bound `Omega(x)` and the other for the upper bound `O(x)`. The lower bound measure is applied to the problem: you are stating that the problem cannot be solved in less than `x` (asymptotically). This usually requires a different proof strategy than the upper bound, where you prove that a given algorithm will actually solve the problem and not exceed the time given by `x` (asymptotically).

Comment: So an algorithm's best case can be both `O(n log n)` and `O(n^2)` because if it's in `O(n^2)` it must also be in `O(n log n)`? By that reasoning, is it also true that merge-sort's worse case is also in `O(n^3)` and `O(n!)`. What I have trouble with is imagining a scenario that shows the running time to be, for example, factorial. Does that even exist?

Comment: @Jon: [Solving the traveling salesman problem via brute-force search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities) is factorial running time algorithm.

Comment: @Jon: no. When we say that merge sort's best case runtime is `O(n log n)` and `O(n^2)`, this means that merge sort needs at most `O(n log n)` on already sorted inputs (because those are the best case inputs for merge sort). Because of that, it must also be in `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can merge sort's worst-case be `O(n*log(n))` but also `O(n^2)`?

Because the **notation** `f(n) = O(g(n))` means that `f(n)` is asymptotically smaller-than-or-equal-to `g(n)`. Perhaps a less misleading notation would be `f(n) <= O(g(n))`. Since `n ^ 2` is asymptotically greater than or equal to `n * log n`, the above inequality holds.

As to your first question: determining an average running time is usually a lot trickier and more involved than determining an upper bound on the worst case. Anyway, [here's a nice explanation I've found for you](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/merge-sort/a/analysis-of-merge-sort).