# Big Oh Complexity of Merge Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

I had a lecture on Big Oh for Merge Sort and I'm confused.

What was shown is:

0 Merges [<----- n -------->] = n

1 Merge  [<--n/2--][-n/2--->] = (n/2 + n/2) = n

2 Merges [n/4][n/4][n/4][n/4] = 2(n/4 + n/4) = n

....

**log(n)** merges = n

Total = (n + n + n + ... + n) = lg n 
= O(n log n)

I don't understand why (n + n + ... + n) can also be expressed as log base 2 of n and how they got for 2 merges = 2(n/4 + n/4)

Comment: They taught us that apparently it can also be written as Big-Oh as well :o

Comment: ok maybe, never saw it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of the following part written in your question,

> 0 Merges [<----- n -------->] = n
>
> 1 Merge [<--n/2--][-n/2--->] = (n/2 + n/2) = n
>
> 2 Merges [n/4][n/4][n/4][n/4] = 2(n/4 + n/4) = n
>
> ....
>
> n merges = n  --This line is incorrect!

is wrong. You will not have total n merges of size n, but Log n merges of size n.

At every level, you divide the problem size into 2 problems of half the size. As you continue diving, the total divisions that you can do is Log n. (How? Let's say total divisions possible is x. Then n = 2<sup>x</sup> or x = Log<sub>2</sub>n.)

Since at each level you do a total work of O(n), therefore for Log n levels, the sum total of all work done will be O(n Log n).

Answer (score 2):

In the case of 1 merge, you have two sub arrays to be sorted where each sub-array will take time proportional to **n/2** to be sorted. In that sense, to sort those two sub-arrays you need a time proportional to **n**.

Similarly, when you are doing 2 merges, there are 4 sub arrays to be sorted where each will be taking a time proportional to **n/4** which will again sum up to **n**.

Similarly, if you have **n** merges, it will take a time proportional to **n** to sort all the sub-arrays. In that sense, we can write the time taken by merge sort as follows.

> T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + n

You will understand that this recursive call can go deep (say to a height of **h**) until `n/(2^h) = 1`. By taking log here, we get **h=log(n)**. That is how log(n) came to the scene. Here **log** is taken from base 2.

Since you have **log(n)** steps where each step takes a time proportional to **n**, total time taken can be expressed as,

> n * log(n)

In big O notations, we give this as an upper bound `O(nlog(n))`. Hope you got the idea.

Following image of the recursion tree will enlighten you further.
[image]

Comment: Did you generate the tree somehow or did you find it? I am curious.

Comment: @synchronizer: It is a commonly available picture. I used it way back in one of my own [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35468852/1835769).

Answer (score 0):

You've got a deep of log(n) and a width of n for your tree. :)

Comment: What is deep of log(n)?

Comment: Sorry for that confusing answer. @Imesha Sudasingha brought a lovely diagram of what's deep and width are.

Answer (score 0):

The log portion is the result of "how many times can I split my data in two before I have only one element left?" This is the depth of your recursion tree. The multiple of n comes from the fact that for each of those levels in the tree you'll look at every element in your data set once after all merge steps at that level.

```
recurse downwards:
    n unsorted elements
  [n/2][n/2] split until singletons...
  ...
merge n elements at each step when recursing back up
  [][][]...[][][]
  [ ] ... [ ]
  ...
  [n/2][n/2]
  n sorted elements
```

Comment: log base 2 of n is the number of times it takes to split your data set until only singletons remain. You have "n" per level because in all merge step at a particular level you end up iterating over the entirety of each subarray. Imssha's answer is more specific I admit. Hopefully I've helped a little.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Each merge takes O(n) as you demonstrated. The number of merges you need to do is log n (base 2), because each merge doubles the size of the sorted sections.