# Find tightest big-O

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

I'm trying to learn and understand how to find tightest big O notation. Here I need to find tightest big-O notation for these algorithms, and  I did the calculating for the running time.

Now I need to prove or find the tightest big-O notation but I'm not sure where should I start.

1) `2 n^2+ 2 n +2= O(n^2)`

2) `6 n log n +4n +2 =O (n log n)`

3) `6 X1000 n+ 4n +2 = O(n)`

Not really sure how to solve this part from question. How I make sure my equation is tightest big-O?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for Big Theta? I'm not really sure what you are asking. Is this a homework question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%D3%A8-notation-represent

Comment: yes this is the question finding tightest big O notation . I think it's to find Thita as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Simply said : You take the one that is "highest" term and remove all constant multipliers.

The reasoning behind this is that as `n` grows, the highest term will contribute the most to the total time. So rest will become negligible for big enough `n`. And removing the constant multipliers is in definition of time complexity.

Comment: Could explain more I removed all constant and remain only big which is LHS . IS there any way to prove tightest big-O notation?